# Best place to retry a task in Django: requests or celery task

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-requests, celery, urllib3

I am hitting an API using `requests` library in Django inside a `celery` task. To be very specific, it fetches some record from `database`, prepares a `json` and does a `POST` request. In the certain case scenario, the call fails with `500` error code. I want to retry the `POST` request again. What's the best way to go about it and why?

- Retry the Celery task itself ([See implementation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions))
- Retry the request using `urllib.util.retry` ([See full implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121365/implementing-retry-for-requests-in-python))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Celery job runs in a separate process. In your case, repeating a 500-returned POST request has nothing to do with creating another process. One process will and should be enough of handling such request. So you need to retry the request using `urllib.util.retry` in the same Celery job and then terminate the job until you get a response with code 200.

Comment: I have a lot of elements in the queue that require to be posted. What is the disadvantage of using retry in celery? @cagrias

Comment: You have only one thing to do: repeat a request until you reach a successful response. As I said, creating a separate celery job will create another process. As making that request from two different processes won't change the result of your request, you do not need to create a separate celery job.

Comment: Celery retry will unnecessary hit your database as many times as it retries - something you really want to avoid...