# Python - Renaming Files + Loop

Tags: python, loops

I Want a script that renames a file on my computer to something random every second, I have the code to rename it here

```
import os
os.rename('Original-File-Name', 'New-File-Name')
```

Here's the script that outputs a random letter

```
import string
import random
string.ascii_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
```

I Want it to rename the file with a random letter every second, how would I do that? (I'm not very good with loops)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add infinite loop:

```
import time

old_file_name = 'file name here'
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    new_file_name = generate_random_name()
    rename_file(old_file_name, new_file_name)
    old_file_name = new_file_name
```

Also you should save new random file name, to rename it in next second

Comment: **How would I change the name to something random?**

`import os`

import random

import string

import time

time.sleep(1)

String = string.ascii_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

`Random = random.choice(String)`

`while True:`
   ` time.sleep(1)`
 `os.rename('Original-File-Name', Random);`

Comment: 1. generate something random, 2. change name

Comment: Since the name has changed I need to change the "Original-File-Name" With the new one

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\ModuleTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    new_file_name = generate_random_name()
NameError: name 'generate_random_name' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import os 
import random 
import string 
import time 
String = string.ascii_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" 
Random = random.choice(String) 
while True: 
    time.sleep(1) 
    name = str(time.time()).split('.')
    os.rename('Original-File-Name', Random+name[0]+'_'+name[1]);
```