# Call a python function on specific timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, timestamp, python-requests

I am trying to send a query to an API every full minute because the API updates its data every minute and I want the updated data immediately. It is important that the timing is very precise, I want to run everything continuously in the end.

This is vaguely what I am trying to do:

```
import time, sched

time = 1549667056000  # starting timestamp

def get_data():  # function to get some data from the API via requests
    #gets the Data

while true:
    s.scheduler(time)
    s.run(get_data())  # gets the data on the specified time(stamp)
    time = time + 60000  # adds 1 minute to the timestamp
```

Shall I do it this way, or is there a even smarter way of getting data from a REST Api exactly every full minute?

Comment: What about using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: As far as I know I can only start an entire python process with corn, not a function.
I have to load a tensorflow model later on, which takes time that I dont have in this scenario. So I'd like to load the Model and feed it the Data every minute.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)

For Python < 3.7

```
import asyncio

def get_data():
    print("Getting data")

async def main():
    while true:
        get_data()
        await asyncio.wait(MINUTE)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

For Python 3.7+

```
import asyncio

def get_data():
    print("Getting data")

async def main():
    while true:
        get_data()
        await asyncio.wait(60)

#This is the only thing that changes
asyncio.run(main)
```

**edit**

As per your comment, if you're really worried about making sure this gets called every 60 seconds.

You could implement a way to take the time before `get_data` is called and subtract that from 60, just need to make sure if `get_data` does take over 60 secs to wait 0 secs or not at all.

Something like this for your `main()` should work:

```
#make sure to:
import time

async def main():
    while true:
        t = time.time()
        get_data()
        time_diff = int(time.time() - t)
        await asyncio.wait(max(60 - time_diff, 0))
```

Comment: Thx for the answer.
The problem is that the API request takes some time, so I have this time + the 60 seconds which will drag the whole "schedule" behind (so I have 61 secs instead of 60 at every iteration), which leads to the problem that I do not meet the next full minute.

Comment: That shouldn't really matter much at all because every *roughly* 60 seconds you're getting the newest data, but if you insist I edited my answer with a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for helping out.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/9025949) worked for me pretty well in the end:

```
import time
starttime = time.time()
while True:
  print(time.time())
  time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

I let it run over night, there was no shift overtime. The time between the executions is exactly 60, no matter how long the code in the loop takes to execute.