# how to restart my code every 5 min at python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

my code sometimes work in 17 sec sometimes 23 sec sometimes 40 seconds it changes with my connection speed and with datas that i get. but i want to repeat working in every next 5 min like 12:05 12:10 12:15. but because of working time it changes like 12:05 12:11 12:16. my code is running all day because of time difference at the end of the day i get nearly 30 minute loos. if you help me i ll be glad have a nice day for all

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
def main():
present_time=datetime.now()

 *****MY CODE HERE*****
print(datetime.strftime(present_time,"%X"))
while True:
     main()
     time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: You want the code to run every 5 minutes but sometimes it takes more than 5 minutes for the code to finish. Do you want code to stop in middle of execution then?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad yes i want my code to run every 5 minutes. but its working at 17 or 23 or 40 seconds. and when i type time.sleep(300) it takes more then 5 minutes and time slips to other minute.

Comment: @roganjosh yes i wanna mean 40 seconds. sorry about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Comment: Look up apscheduler

Comment: and how about use cron and execute your script every 5 mins? its valid for you?

Comment: @FelixMartinez i ve checked cron and it can be usefull. do you know hot to use cron?

Comment: crontab tutorial: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want something like the following, which will cause the program to sleep up till the next 5 minute mark at most. If the run time of your code exceeds 5 minutes, it will not sleep, and instead start the next 5 minute interval immediately.

```
from time import time, sleep

def main():
    # *****YOUR CODE HERE*****

while True:
    start_time = time()
    main()
    sleep(max(0, 5 * 60 + start_time - time()))
```

Comment: it doesnt work exactly that i want mate

Comment: @AlperAşan I don't understand. Your post seems to suggest you want it to start / stop at exact 5-minute schedules, and this is what my code does.

Comment: i want it to work every 5 minutes with in code working time. my problem is code is working at different times. sometime 17 sec or 20 sec or 40 sec. when i type this code it works 5:17 minutes or 5:20 minutes. did i explain my problem mate?

Comment: @AlperAşan my code accounts for that. If your code takes 4min 50sec, the above code will sleep for 10 seconds, for a total run time 5 minutes. You can try it by substituting `5 * 60` for some smaller, easier to measure time frame if you don't believe me.

Comment: @AlperAşan Have you removed the `sleep(300)` from your original code?

Comment: @AlperAşan once you've run this code and seen it does in fact work, please consider retracting your downvote, unless there are further issues.

Comment: @DillonDavis The OP can't be the downvoter, as he doesn't have the necessary (125) reputation to do that.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille ah, you're right. By the tone of his comments it sounded like he was replying as the downvoter.

Comment: @DillonDavis maybe you are getting angry to me but i typed your code and first data time is 20:36:28 and second data time is 20:42:11. i wanna mean that i want second data time at 20:41:28 thats all.