# Python pandas refresh dataframe in console

Tags: python, pandas, refresh

I have a dataframe which is being supplied values continuously and I want it to refresh in my console, with the dataframe in the same position with only the values changing, is that possible?
Or are there alternatives to pandas that could be used to have the same effect?

Comment: Create a loop and refresh the dataframe every few minutes! Use this as a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python

Comment: But how would that ensure the dataframe refreshes in the same position?

Comment: Post your code please!