# Is there a way to run a function every x seconds? (DPS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

My original Solution was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/12962821) Comment on a similar question. However, if I do that and implement this
into different parts of my code, it stops counting up the in-game Counter of CASH.

```
CASH = 0
DPS = 5
HPofMonster = 10
starttime=time.time()

def handle_monster():
    global HPofMonster, CASH
    if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if GEN1.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y) and event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            HPofMonster -= 1
            print('click')
            pass
        else:
            print('Not Pushed OR not on Monster')
            pass
    else:
        print('Mouse not focused')
        pass
    if HPofMonster < 0:
        CASH += 5
        HPofMonster = 10
        print('reset')

def handle_dps():
    global HPofMonster
    HPofMonster -= DPS
    print("tick")
    time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0))


def game_loop():
    while True:
        handle_dps()
        handle_monster()
        update_text()
        handle_events()



def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption('Clicker')
    game_loop()


main()
```

When I don´t move my Mouse, my console looks like this:

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*reset*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*reset*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*tick*

*Not Pushed OR not on Monster*

*reset*

*Mouse not focused*

*Process finished with exit code 0*

Here is the entire code:

```
import pygame, threading, time

from threading import Event, Thread
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
CASH = 0
DPS = 5
HPofMonster = 10
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
BUTTON_COLOR = (0, 255, 0)
starttime=time.time()

FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('monospace', 15)

# Main Screen for drawing buttons
DRAW_SCREEN = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
DRAW_SCREEN.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

# Buttons
GEN1 = pygame.draw.rect(DRAW_SCREEN, BUTTON_COLOR, pygame.Rect(200, 200, 200, 200), 1)
GEN1_LABEL = FONT.render('Defeat the Monster', 1, (255, 255, 0))


def handle_monster():
    global HPofMonster, CASH
    if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if GEN1.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y) and event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            HPofMonster -= 1
            print('click')
            pass
        else:
            print('Not Pushed OR not on Monster')
            pass
    else:
        print('Mouse not focused')
        pass
    if HPofMonster < 0:
        CASH += 5
        HPofMonster = 10
        print('reset')


def handle_events():
    event_dict = {
        pygame.QUIT: exit,
    }
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type in event_dict:
            event_dict[event.type]()


def update_text():
    global CASH_LABEL, DPS_LABEL, GEN1_LABEL, DPS, CASH
    WINDOW.blit(DRAW_SCREEN, (0, 0))
    WINDOW.blit(GEN1_LABEL, (10, 108))
    CASH_LABEL = FONT.render('Total Cash: ${}'.format(CASH), 1, (255, 255, 0))
    DPS_LABEL = FONT.render('Total DPS: ${}'.format(DPS), 1, (255, 65, 0))
    WINDOW.blit(CASH_LABEL, (0, 0))
    WINDOW.blit(DPS_LABEL, (0, 20))
    pygame.display.flip()


def handle_dps():
    global HPofMonster
    HPofMonster -= DPS
    print("tick")


def game_loop():
    while True:
        handle_dps()
        handle_monster()
        update_text()
        handle_events()



def main():
    pygame.display.set_caption('Clicker')
    game_loop()


main()
```

Comment: you cannot use `time.sleep` in a pygame loop. You have to install a timer. pygame is SDL-based, so this is probably possible

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `time.sleep()` in a event-driven program.  It blocks the event-loop, and on some systems the window manager or outlying operating system will consider the program to have stopped and/or crashed.  The program must continually process incoming events.

An easy way to do this in pygame is to use the real-time system clock function `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which returns the number of milliseconds since the program started, and it keeps increasing *forever*.  If you want something to trigger in the future, set a timestamp like:

```
future_timestamp = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 15000   # 15 seconds from now

...

# somewhere else in the code, maybe in the main loop
time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
if ( future_timestamp < time_now ):
    # do the thing that had to happen
    do_that_thing()
    # re-set the timer for next time
    future_timestamp = time_now + 15000
```

Another simple way to implement something that happens periodically is to setup a pygame timer:

```
pygame.time.set_timer( pygame.USEREVENT + 1, 3500 )   # Cash every 3500 milliseconds

# Main Loop 
while not exiting:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
           done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1 ):
           CASH += 1   
           # reset the event-timer
           pygame.time.set_timer( pygame.USEREVENT + 1, 3500 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time.sleep` use `pygame.time.delay()`or `pygame.time.wait()`.

Here is the link of official pygame time events: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html