# How to time the execution of code in a loop?

Tags: python

I want to make a programme who print "hey" every 5 seconds 
mine is printing every 5 seconds but more than one time.

```
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.today()
objectif = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 50)
later = objectif+now

inc = 0

while later > datetime.datetime.today():
    if datetime.datetime.today().second%5==0 and later.microsecond == datetime.datetime.today().microsecond:
        print "hey"
```

How can I print "hey" only one time per 5 seconds?

Comment: An easy way to print every 5 seconds is to use `time.sleep(5)`. Also, you are using python 2.x, consider upgrading to python 3.x. Python 2 is at end-of-life and its best to learn with the new stuff.

Comment: There are mountains of resources on this topic, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. Have you done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

The following will print 'hey' ever 5 seconds to a limit of 50 seconds

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

end_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 50)

while end_time > datetime.datetime.now():
    print("hey")
    sleep(5)
```