# is there a deadlock in my simple loop code

Tags: python, while-loop, microservices, deadlock, docker-container

I have a micro service with a job that needs to happen only if a different server is up.
for a few weeks it works great, if the server was down, the micro service sleeps a bit without doing the job (as should) and if the server was up - the job was done.
the server is never down for more then a few minutes (for sure! the server is highly monitored), so the job is skipped 2-3 times tops.

Today I entered my Docker Container and noticed in the logs that the job didn't even try to continue for a few weeks now (bad choice not to monitor I know), indicating, I assume that some kind of deadlock happened.
I also assume that the problem is with my Exception handling, could use some advice I work alone.

```
def is_server_healthy():
    url = "url" #correct url for health check path
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as ex:
        LOGGER.error(f"Can't health check!{ex}")
    finally:
        pass

    return res

def init():
    while True:
        LOGGER.info(f"Sleeping for {SLEEP_TIME} Minutes")
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*ONE_MINUTE)

        res = is_server_healthy()

        if res.status_code == 200:
            my_api.DoJob()
            LOGGER.info(f"Server is: {res.text}")
        else:
            LOGGER.info(f"Server is down... {res.status_code}")
```

(The names of the variables were changed to simplify the question)

The health check is simple enough - return "up" if up. anything else considered to be down, so unless status 200 and "up" came back I consider the server to be down.

Comment: shouldn't you indent the `return res` more?

Comment: @alex yes, I did't copy well. please ignore ill edit

Comment: Shouldn't you cron-tab a single execution every minute of your check script without the `while True:` loop? Or try some of the other methods in [what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds)

Comment: The only line that can lead to an unhandled exception is `my_api.DoJob()`. All the other lines won't cause an exception and the lines that could are handled by a try except.

Comment: @TinNguyes - there are. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your server is down you get a non-captured error:

```
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

Why? See:

```
def is_server_healthy():
    url = "don't care"
    try:
        raise Exception()  # simulate fail
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Can't health check!{ex}")
    finally:
        pass

    return res   ## name is not known ;o)

res = is_server_healthy()
if res.status_code == 200:   # here, next exception bound to happen
    my_api.DoJob()
    LOGGER.info(f"Server is: {res.text}")
else:
    LOGGER.info(f"Server is down... {res.status_code}")
```

Even if you declared the name, it would try to access some attribute thats not there:

> ```
> if res.status_code == 200:   # here - object has no attribute 'status_code'   
>     my_api.DoJob()
>     LOGGER.info(f"Server is: {res.text}")
> else:
>     LOGGER.info(f"Server is down... {res.status_code}")
> ```

would try to access a member thats simply not there => Exception, and process gone.

---

You are probably better off using some system-specific way to call your script once every minute (Cron Jobs, Task Scheduler) then idling in a `while True:` with sleep.

Comment: I think I just realise what you said - 
I changed that line to be:
if hasattr(res, "status_code") and res.status_code == 200: