# Best way to execute a function with time increments in Twisted?

Tags: python, loops, timeout, twisted

Note, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds) which works as expected.

I had like to execute a function every X seconds and increment by 2 seconds on every successive run.

So for an example, the first time the function should run at 3 seconds, then it should run at 5, then it should run at 7 seconds and so on...

First run - 3 seconds
Second run - 5 seconds
Third run - 7 seconds
and so on...

My code is

```py
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

timeout = 3 # three seconds

def doWork():
    #do work here
    pass

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every three seconds

reactor.run()
```

Comment: LoopingCall can't do this.  What else have you tried?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone - Sorry haven't tried other approaches as I am wanting to use Twisted to handle this as I also use Qt5rector and scrapy in my program both of which work on Twisted. Can you give pointers as what other things I should look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reactor.callLater(n, fn, ...)`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.html#callLater)

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Worker:

    max_timeout = 11
    increment = 2

    def __call__(self, interval):
        interval += self.increment          # <-- increment interval
        if interval > self.max_timeout:
            interval = self.max_timeout     # <-- don't go over max

        print(f"do work...{interval} interval")

        # call the func after N seconds
        reactor.callLater(interval, self, interval)

def main():
    worker = Worker()
    reactor.callLater(3, worker, 3)         # <-- start in 3 seconds
    reactor.run()

main()
```

If there comes a point in the code where you need to stop, then simply have logic that doesn't call `reactor.callLater()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question, this works as expected. Much obliged.