# Python async generator function without time drift

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to emulated the generation of a sequence of numbers as shown in the code below. I want to execute this at regular intervals without time drift and *without* keeping track of the number of times serial_sequence() has been called, i.e. without using the variable *num*.
How can this be done?

In the example code, delay2 is always 0.1, but it should be slightly less since the event loop is busy elsewhere between calls to serial_sequence(). Thus the elapsed time is over 2.0 seconds.

```py
import  asyncio
import time
rx_data = list()
EOT = 20

async def serial_sequence():
    '''async generator function that simulates incoming sequence of serial data'''
    num = 0
    tprev = time.time()

    while True:
        dt = time.time() - tprev
        delay2 = 0.1 - dt #Want to avoid time drift
        print('dt: {}'.format(dt))
        print('delay2: {}'.format(delay2))
        await asyncio.sleep(delay2) #simulated IO delay
        tprev = time.time()
        num += 1
        yield  num

async def read_serial1():
    gen = serial_sequence()
    while(True):
        data = await gen.__anext__()
        rx_data.append(data)
        print('read_serial1:', data)
        if data == EOT:
            break
    return rx_data

async def main():
    start = time.time()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(read_serial1())
    await(task1)
    stop = time.time()
    print('Elapsed: {}'.format(stop-start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the while loop itself needs some time to compute. The timedrift in your example accumulates because you base `dt` on the time of the previous timestep `tprev`.

You could instead use the absolute starting time of `serial_sequence` as point of reference like so:

```py
async def serial_sequence():
    '''async generator function that simulates incoming sequence of serial data'''
    num = 0
    starttime = time.time()

    while True:
        dt = (time.time() - starttime) % 0.1
        delay2 = 0.1 - dt #Want to avoid time drift
        print('dt: {}'.format(dt))
        print('delay2: {}'.format(delay2))
        await asyncio.sleep(delay2) #simulated IO delay
        tprev = time.time()
        num += 1
        yield num
```

Compare the accumulation by changing `EOT`. I.e. Doubling `EOT` results in double the time drift for your solution, while it is approximately constant for this one.

My answer is largely based on [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/7530362).