# How to run a code after every 5 minutes from a specific time from 9:15 am to 3:30 pm?

Tags: python

I want to run a script at every 5 minutes but for the time when I run it, I want it to wait for divisible 5 minutes. For ex - current time is 11:32:15 am, so for the first time I would like it to run from 11:35 and then after every 5 minutes till 3:15 pm

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What went wrong?

Comment: Use `cron` to run a command on a schedule.

Comment: The generic answer is indeed `cron`, but if you have a long-running Python process in which you want to schedule things, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59203700/12299000) about the `schedule` module.

Comment: The general algorithm is: get the current time, compute the delay till the next run, sleep the computed amout, run your command. For recurring commands put that into a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, it is flexible for this kind of task.

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(5).minute.until("2030-01-01 03:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```