# A loop runs once every 10 mins in forever loop Python

Tags: python

I have a forever loop that rebalance my portfolio. I call an exchange API which basically does not cost anything as long as I stay within their rate limit (1-2 call per sec), so I loop them forever with minimal sleep time (10 sec).

Then I want to add an API call from Coinmarketcap as a small loop that run once every 10 mins. This is done to avoid their 'free' API limit (333 call/day, and I use 2 calls per loop).

so My forever loop is simply:

```
while True:
    try:
       countCMC = 0

       for loop
          
          if countCMC == 0 or countCMC % 60 == 0:
             get Coinmarketcap api......
          
          countCMC = countCMC + 1

          run bunches of rebalance algo......
          time.sleep(10)
    except:
       ....
```

I want to call Coinmarketcap and parse their data to variables, and then use them in my rebalance algo. May be a small loop inside "try" with sleep time?

**Update:** I have tried to add count and then use modulo, so it runs at the beginning and every 60x10 = 600 sec thereafter. Wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: So, you'll have to count.  You'll do your Coinmarketcap every 60 times through your loop.

Comment: I use count as you suggested and modulo. Wonder if there is a better or more efficient way

Comment: hello, guess this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds

Comment: by the way "if countCMC == 0 or countCMC % 60 == 0:" can be simplified to "if countCMC % 60 == 0:" because 0%60 = 0

Comment: You can take help of Threads here. Run both in different threads and collect the results as you need.

Comment: You are sleeping for 10 seconds between every action you take.  Efficiency is simply not a factor here.  Don't waste time optimizing this.