# How can I loop this script every 30 seconds?

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to loop this script every 30 seconds.

```py
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q='safe dev', lang='en', tweet_mode='extended').items(100)
print(tweet.full_text, tweet.created_at)
```

I tried while true but it's not showing results.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/how-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds?rq=1) help you?

Comment: Show the code that didn't work. A `while` and a `sleep` should work.

Comment: while True:
        for tweet in tweets:
            time.sleep(5)
            print(tweet.full_text, tweet.created_at)

Comment: My problem is it's showing each results every 5 seconds but what I am trying to do is repeat the function. What I am trying to do is instead of keep clicking the run script. I want it to run every 30 seconds so I can keep track if there's any new data would show up.