# crontab in python

Tags: python, cron

I'm writing code in python for some sort of daemon that has to execute a specific action at a certain instance in time defined by a crontab string.
Is there a module I can use?
If not, can someone paste/link an algorithm I can use to check whether the instance of time defined by the crontab has occured in the time from when the previous check was done.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your question.  "check whether the instance of time defined by the crontab has occured in the time from when the previous check "  is pretty hard to parse.

Comment: The daemon sleeps for eg. 2min, and when it starts working again I want to check if in those 2 min the instance occurred..

Comment: Please update the question -- don't add comments to clarify your question -- update your question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) ftw

Answer (score 1):

[Kronos](http://www.razorvine.net/download/kronos.py) is another option.

Here is a similar SO  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [pycron](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm).