# Python: How to run a def in the background

Tags: python

How can I run a python definition now, but do more stuff after a certain time. So it's kind of running the script silently in the background until certain condition is met?

Thank you

Comment: when the time is pass midnite, for example?

Comment: cron it on linux, schedule it on Windows [control panel > scheduled tasks > Add scheduled task] You may also be interested to have a look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551780/

Comment: if you want to run this "def" while you code is running (ie, in the background of your own code), you should look for a mult-thread code. if you want to execute your whole application after some time you should consider @verisimilitude comment.

Comment: thank you all. I'll try scheduled task

Comment: You could even use the `&` operator to shell-execute it in the background.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cron job to execute a python script at a certain time. You can find a similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826882/crontab-in-python). If you looking for a pure python implementation, [this answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374207/842837).