# Scheduling Python Programs

Tags: python, time, python-3.x

How would you go about a having a function check something every ten minutes?
I would like to check a directory for new files every ten minutes. I know python has a time library but can it be used for this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python.  Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038907/run-a-task-at-specific-intervals-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sched](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sched.html#module-sched) module is worth a look.

Comment: How would i use time.sleep in a loop?

Comment: @Morpheus: You wouldn't use `time.sleep()` in a loop with `sched`.

Answer (score 0):

[`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
time.sleep(10*60)
```

you might want to look into `cron` or Scheduled Tasks services of the OS.

Comment: `sleep` is an awful way to do this; it is inaccurate and inflexible. Depending on the task, an OS scheduler like `cron` would be a great way to go.

Comment: @Mike: and why do you think that this method should be precise?

Answer (score 0):

for checking of files, you may want to try [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)