# How to replace launchd scheduling with a Python program

Tags: python, macos, launchd

The Mac OS X system startup program [*launchd*](http://17.254.2.129/macosx/launchd.html) enables job scheduling (similar to *cron*.) By creating a *launchd* agent, one can trigger programs through one of the following events:

- an interval of time has elapsed
- a certain calendar date has come
- a file path has been modified
- something has been placed in a certain directory (queue directory)
- a volume has been mounted

I have previously relied on launchd to start a collection of Python scripts for automating an OS X system. However, since adding a new script also often requires the installation of a new launchd agent for starting it, I would like take *launchd* out of the equation. A Python program should wait and watch for events like those above to occur, then dispatch the appropriate routine.

Is there a Python module which is appropriate for detecting events like those above? Or, as a more general question, how can I replace *launchd* in this setting using Python (and possibly AppleScript via the AppScript bridge)? Sorry if the question is rather vague. Reading suggestions are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filesystem-monitoring problem, perhaps you are looking for [pyfsevents](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfsevents/0.2b1). According to [this post](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-darwin-development/107170-inotify-mac.html),

> FSEvents API notifies your application
>   when changes occur in the file system.
>   You can use file system events to
>   monitor directories for any changes,
>   such as the creation, modification, or
>   removal of contained files and
>   directories.

Comment: Thanks, I can use this for volume detection and queue directories.

Still looking for something that makes watching for timed events easy.

Comment: @D-Bug: For scheduling events after an elapsed amount of time, you should be able to use the `sched` module -- it's in the standard library. You might also want to check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: A follow-up question on pyfsevents: 
It seems that a call to pyfsevents.listen() blocks the entire python process, not just the calling thread. I would like to have a thread waiting for incoming file system events. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @D-Bug: Hmm.. Sorry; I have no first-hand experience with pyfsevents.

Comment: Maybe if you post a new question with pyfsevents as a tag, it will attract people knowledgable about the subject