# Schedule a repeating event in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, timing

I'm trying to schedule a repeating event to run every minute in Python 3.

I've seen class `sched.scheduler` but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it. I've heard mentions I could use multiple threads for this, which I wouldn't mind doing.

I'm basically requesting some JSON and then parsing it; its value changes over time.

To use `sched.scheduler` I have to create a loop to request it to schedule the even to run for one hour:

```
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

# Schedule the event. THIS IS UGLY!
for i in range(60):
    scheduler.enter(3600 * i, 1, query_rate_limit, ())

scheduler.run()
```

What other ways to do this are there?

Comment: Duplicate of all of the "schedule" question for Python 2.  All of these:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+schedule

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/474528/3701431

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects), but that also schedules a one-off event, similarly to the `.enter` method of scheduler objects.

The normal pattern (in any language) to transform a one-off scheduler into a periodic scheduler is to have each event re-schedule itself at the specified interval.  For example, with `sched`, I would not use a loop like you're doing, but rather something like:

```
def periodic(scheduler, interval, action, actionargs=()):
    scheduler.enter(interval, 1, periodic,
                    (scheduler, interval, action, actionargs))
    action(*actionargs)
```

and initiate the whole "forever periodic schedule" with a call

```
periodic(scheduler, 3600, query_rate_limit)
```

Or, I could use `threading.Timer` instead of `scheduler.enter`, but the pattern's quite similar.

If you need a more refined variation (e.g., stop the periodic rescheduling at a given time or upon certain conditions), that's not too hard to accomodate with a few extra parameters.

Comment: Well, in java I have

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()

And real multithreading.
And everybody saying that in python we write less code... Um-hum...
Just saying...

Comment: @user1685095 there are *always* exceptions to any generalized statement like that, sadly.

Comment: @Wallacoloo does that mean there *aren't* always exceptions? :)

Comment: @user1685095 not so fast! Try coding that without multiple imports, extending TimerTask, providing a `run` method, and adding a separate class to run the timer as well as creating all those objects.  Probably around 15 lines of code.  (Unless you have a cleaner way to do it; I'm not the greatest at Java.)

Comment: Based on Alex Martelli's answer, I have implemented decorator version which is more easier to integrated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758861/482899

Comment: @jdk1.0 No need to do all this in modern Java. It is quite concise in this case.

Answer (score 41):

You could use [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule). It works on Python 2.7 and 3.3 and is rather lightweight:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
   print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: why while loop?, wouldn't it run like cron jobs ?

Comment: @Jaydev the while loop is required if the code is running in the main thread

Comment: webserver stop serving file with this package

Comment: This hangs when using a GUI

Answer (score 25):

My humble take on the subject:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer     = None
        self.function   = function
        self.interval   = interval
        self.args       = args
        self.kwargs     = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
```

Usage:

```
from time import sleep

def hello(name):
    print "Hello %s!" % name

print "starting..."
rt = RepeatedTimer(1, hello, "World") # it auto-starts, no need of rt.start()
try:
    sleep(5) # your long-running job goes here...
finally:
    rt.stop() # better in a try/finally block to make sure the program ends!
```

Features:

- Standard library only, no external dependencies
- Uses the pattern suggested by Alex Martnelli
- `start()` and `stop()` are safe to call multiple times even if the timer has already started/stopped
- function to be called can have positional and named arguments
- You can change `interval` anytime, it will be effective after next run. Same for `args`, `kwargs` and even `function`!

Comment: Beautiful class but it has a little problem if start() is executed in a loop.
It may pass the is_running check due to the _run function executed in another thread. So the last self._timer is reassigned and it cannot be stopped.
Check out my answer for the proper version.

Comment: @fdb: I'm not sure I understood your points. If you execute `start()` in a loop using the *same*  class instance, it won't do anything. If you create a *new* instance, it will trigger a different timer (allowing you to have multiple simultaneous timers). As for multithreading, yes, it's excepted that each `start()` (or `__init__()` to be called in the same thread

Comment: It's a my mistake with "loop" word: I mean a fast calling (implemented with a do...loop) to the start() function.
Fast enought to be more fast than the setting of "is_running" flag by the _run() function.

Answer (score 12):

Based on MestreLion answer, it solve a little problem with multithreading:

```
from threading import Timer, Lock

class Periodic(object):
    """
    A periodic task running in threading.Timers
    """

    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._timer = None
        self.function = function
        self.interval = interval
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self._stopped = True
        if kwargs.pop('autostart', True):
            self.start()

    def start(self, from_run=False):
        self._lock.acquire()
        if from_run or self._stopped:
            self._stopped = False
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
        self._lock.release()

    def _run(self):
        self.start(from_run=True)
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def stop(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        self._stopped = True
        self._timer.cancel()
        self._lock.release()
```

Comment: Ha I was just putting the lock into the original. It is truly necessary. Thanks this is the correct version of MestreLion

Comment: If the `function` being called takes longer to execute than the interval, for example blocking on a network I/O or something, this has the potential to stack them up.  I would think most use cases would want to start the timer again *after* the function returns.

Comment: @JoeHolloway The function will be re-scheduled even if it raises an exception. One solution is to swap the order of the `self.start` and `self.function` calls, but this might break the timing consistency.

Comment: @Wood Agreed, if you swap the order of the calls, it would be easy to wrap `self.function` in `try/except/finally` to log or otherwise handle exceptions while ensuring the timer is restarted each time. Depends on the use case if timing consistency is more important than not stacking up whatever `self.function` is doing if it can take longer to execute than the timer interval and you don't want to flood it under that condition.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/). It even has a cron-like interface.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
from datetime import timedelta


class ProcessClicksTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=30)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on Alex Martelli's answer, I have implemented *decorator* version which is more easier to integrated.

```
import sched
import time
import datetime
from functools import wraps
from threading import Thread


def async(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func_hl = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        func_hl.start()
        return func_hl
    return async_func


def schedule(interval):
    def decorator(func):
        def periodic(scheduler, interval, action, actionargs=()):
            scheduler.enter(interval, 1, periodic,
                            (scheduler, interval, action, actionargs))
            action(*actionargs)

        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
            periodic(scheduler, interval, func)
            scheduler.run()
        return wrap
    return decorator


@async
@schedule(1)
def periodic_event():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    periodic_event()
    print('end')
```

Comment: This decorator solution is really great, but I have a proposal for a slight improvement:

Add `*args` and `**kwargs` to the scheduled function call like this:
`def decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def periodic(scheduler, interval, action, actionargs=(), kwargs={}):
        scheduler.enter(interval, 1, periodic,
                         (scheduler, interval, action, actionargs, kwargs))
        action(*actionargs, **kwargs)`

and below 

`periodic(scheduler, interval, func, args, kwargs)`

This makes it possible to schedule functions with parameters.

Comment: @opt12 Are the params changed for each schedule?

Comment: Nope, the args are the same for each schedule, but you can decorate any function to be scheduled regularly. No matter whether they take parameters or not. These arguments are tha same for each run, but at least they can be supplied as initial argument.

Answer (score 3):

Doc: [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/)

```py
@sched.cron_schedule(day='last sun')
def some_decorated_task():
    print("I am printed at 00:00:00 on the last Sunday of every month!")
```

Available fields:

```
| Field       | Description                                                    |
|-------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| year        | 4-digit year number                                            |
| month       | month number (1-12)                                            |
| day         | day of the month (1-31)                                        |
| week        | ISO week number (1-53)                                         |
| day_of_week | number or name of weekday (0-6 or mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun) |
| hour        | hour (0-23)                                                    |
| minute      | minute (0-59)                                                  |
| second      | second (0-59)                                                  |
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty non-blocking loop with `Thread`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading,time

def worker():
    print(time.time())
    time.sleep(5)
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()


threads = []
t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
threads.append(t)
t.start()
time.sleep(7)
print("Hello World")
```

There's nothing particularly special, the `worker` creates a new thread of itself with a delay.  Might not be most efficient, but simple enough. [northtree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758861/3701431) would be the way to go if you need more sophisticated solution.

And based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190867/3701431), we can do the same, just with `Timer`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading,time

def hello():
    t = threading.Timer(10.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print( "hello, world",time.time() )

t = threading.Timer(10.0, hello)
t.start()
time.sleep(12)
print("Oh,hai",time.time())
time.sleep(4)
print("How's it going?",time.time())
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to add a check for checking if this thread t is alive? I tried using a try except block and putting t.start() inside the try but it doesnt start the thread!.I just need to run a isAlive() for t to check if its alive

Comment: @toing_toing Frankly, I don't know. I would suggest a global variable to be updated by a thread or a lock-file if you're in Linux environment, but that's an idea from the top of my head and not based in "good practices", only familiarity with Linux. There's an option of using [shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124588/3701431) for such task as well.  Now, I'm not very knowledgeable in multithreaded programming, so I would suggest asking a question on the site and reference this answer so that people can see which code you're trying to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

See my sample

```
import sched, time

def myTask(m,n):
  print n+' '+m

def periodic_queue(interval,func,args=(),priority=1):
  s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
  periodic_task(s,interval,func,args,priority)
  s.run()

def periodic_task(scheduler,interval,func,args,priority):
  func(*args)
  scheduler.enter(interval,priority,periodic_task,
                   (scheduler,interval,func,args,priority))

periodic_queue(1,myTask,('world','hello'))
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than the other 8 answers already here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package, called `ischedule`. For this case, the solution could be as following:

```py
from ischedule import schedule, run_loop
from datetime import timedelta


def query_rate_limit():
    print("query_rate_limit")

schedule(query_rate_limit, interval=60)
run_loop(return_after=timedelta(hours=1))
```

Everything runs on the main thread and there is no busy waiting inside the run_loop. The startup time is very precise, usually within a fraction of a millisecond of the specified time.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the original `threading.Timer()` class implementation and fixing the `run()` method I get something like:

```py
class PeriodicTimer(Thread):
    """A periodic timer that runs indefinitely until cancel() is called."""
    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self.finished = Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet."""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        """Run until canceled"""
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

The `wait()` method called is using a condition variable, so it should be rather efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue a while back so I made a python module [event-scheduler](https://github.com/phluentmed/event-scheduler) to address this. It has a very similar API to the sched library with a few differences:

1. It utilizes a background thread and is always able to accept and run jobs in the background until the scheduler is stopped explicitly (no need for a while loop).
2. It comes with an API to schedule recurring events at a user specified interval until explicitly cancelled.

It can be installed by `pip install event-scheduler`

```py
from event_scheduler import EventScheduler

event_scheduler = EventScheduler()
event_scheduler.start()
# Schedule the recurring event to print "hello world" every 60 seconds with priority 1
# You can use the event_id to cancel the recurring event later
event_id = event_scheduler.enter_recurring(60, 1, print, ("hello world",))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a mimic for setTimeout and setInterval from JavaScript, but in Python.

With this class you can:

1. Set a timeout with an interval ID (through variable, not required).
2. Set an interval in the same wise as a timeout.
3. Set an interval with an ID, and then set a timeout that will cancel the interval in a given amount of time.
4. Set a timeout with an ID and cancel the timeout with another setTimeout.

I know it seems complex but I needed all the functionality it had just like in JavaScript. Note that you will need to pre-create a function and use the function name as a parameter (see code).

```
#If I'm not mistaken, I believe the only modules you need are time and threading. The rest were for something I'm working on.
import time
import math
import pygame
import threading
import ctypes
from sys import exit

#Functions
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timers = {}
        self.timer_id = 0
    
    def setInterval(self, fn, time, *args):
        def interval_callback():
            fn(*args)
            if timer_id in self.timers:
                self.timers[timer_id] = threading.Timer(time/1000, interval_callback)
                self.timers[timer_id].start()

        timer_id = self.timer_id
        self.timer_id += 1
        self.timers[timer_id] = threading.Timer(time/1000, interval_callback)
        self.timers[timer_id].start()
        return timer_id

    def clearInterval(self, timer_id):
        if timer_id in self.timers:
            self.timers[timer_id].cancel()
            del self.timers[timer_id]

    def setTimeout(self, fn, delay, *args, **kwargs):
        def timer_callback():
            self.timers.pop(timer_id, None)
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        
        timer_id = self.timer_id
        self.timer_id += 1
        t = threading.Timer(delay / 1000, timer_callback)
        self.timers[timer_id] = t
        t.start()
        return timer_id
    
    def clearTimeout(self, timer_id):
        t = self.timers.pop(timer_id, None)
        if t is not None:
            t.cancel()
t = Timer()

#Usage Example
lall = t.setInterval(print, 1000, "hi")
t.setTimeout(t.clearInterval, 3000, lall)
```

Hope this helps.