# How can I call function every 30 seconds?

Tags: python, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

I would like to get system  information using SMNT protocol and I would like to refresh this data every 30 seconds. My idea is to run a thread and after getting the data call the sleep function. Is there any other way. for example a built in function which run a given function each 30 seconds in the background?

Comment: The accepted answer of [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) should help you which suggests the [shecd](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [event scheduler](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html). You could schedule a function to be called every 30 seconds, and once called, it could add itself back into the cue to be called in another 30 seconds.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398661/schedule-a-repeating-event-in-python-3) may be of some use to you.