# Does accessing a list change its ref count?

Tags: python, refcounting

The original problem i am dealing with is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124588/898747). I would like to ask an additional question (about Python reference counting) related to the original problem.

Lets say that i have the following script:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
from array import array

list1=[bitarray('00011'), bitarray('00010'), bitarray('11011')]
list2=[array('i',[0,0,0,0]),array('i',[1,1,1,1]),array('i',[2,2,2,2])]

def calculate(l1,l2):
    result1=l1[0]&l1[1]&l1[2]
    result2=l2[0][0]+l2[1][1]+l2[2][2]
return result1, result2

print calculate(list1,list2)
```

Does the reference count of `list1`, `list2` or any of the objects in either lists changes **at some point** when i call `calculate(list1,list2)`?

Just to clarify: I do not mean if the reference count will be the same before and after calling `calculate(list1,list2)`. I mean if the reference count changes at any point during the execution of `calculate(list1,list2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference count of `list1` and `list2` doesn't change, they are just variables and thus string keys in a `locals()` namespace.

The Python list objects that these two variables point to, though, yes, their reference count changes when passed to a function. During the call to the function two *new* variables refer to those lists (`l1` and `l2`) increasing the count, and when the function returns those variables are cleaned up and the ref count goes down again.

Inside the `calculate()` function, you are accessing items of these two lists (`l1[0]`, etc.). Item access could use the `__getitem__` method of objects; methods are created on-the-fly when accessed, and hold a reference to the instance and the underlying function. For a list that is another reference to the list object, and another temporary reference count increase. Once the function has been called and returned it's value, the method is discarded again (nothing is referencing it) and the ref count for the list drops again.

As delnan rightly points out in the comments, for list subscription the `BINARY_SUBSCR` opcode optimizes access (provided the index is an integer) and no method is created *in that specific case*.

The python interpreter, when handling bytecode and values on the stack, is increasing and decreasing reference counts *all the time* though. Take a look through the [Python bytecode evaluation loop](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f26c91bf61bf/Python/ceval.c) and count the number of `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF` occurrences to to get an idea of how common this is.

Comment: +1 There may also be (even shorter-lived) references during the calls to `__getitem__` inside `calculate`, or in preparation of that call (`LOAD_FAST 0 (l1); LOAD_CONST 0; BINARY_SUBSCR`).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that even the line `result1=l1[0]&l1[1]&l1[2]` will modify the reference counts of related objects?

Comment: @anti666: Yes, ref counts can go up and down rapidly.

Comment: Nitpick: As special method lookup happens on the class, and indexing has its own opcode, `l1[0]` etc. probably don't create a bound method object. They still put a temporary reference on the stack though. (And as always, this is all CPython-specific.)

Comment: @delnan: The `BINARY_SUBSCR` will use `__getitem__` in all cases but a list access with an integer. :-) It's special cased, see [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f26c91bf61bf/Python/ceval.c#l1373).

Comment: Even better, but unrelated to my point ;) It never creates a bound method in the general/slow path either (it calls `PyObject_GetItem`, which calls `PySequence_GetItem` for non-mappings, which uses `s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item`), but it always puts an additional reference on the stack (before even reaching `BINARY_SUBSCR`), which requires a refcount change.

Comment: @delnan: `PyObject_GetItem()` will use the `__getitem__` method if one is there to use, of course. I expanded the answer to include information about the bytecode evaluation loop and it's stack.

Comment: Yes, but still not my point. Your third paragraph speaks of **bound methods** for `__getitem__`, but those aren't created by `BINARY_SUBSCR`. `PyObject_GetItem` always directly calls a C-level function pointer stored in the type object, without creating a bound method object for it. It's a valid point for many other cases, and it may be useful to mention that among many other seemingly innocuous things that modify the refcount, but as it stands, it's misleading.

Comment: @delnan: you making me search now.. if a custom object has a `__getitem__` method, I believe that `PyObject_GetItem` ultimately will have to create a method object to call that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22115/discussion-between-delnan-and-martijn-pieters)