# Taking advantage of fork system call to avoid read/writing or serializing altogether?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, fork, dask

I am using mac book and therefore, multiprocessing will use fork system call instead of spawning a new process. Also, I am using Python (with multiprocessing or Dask).

I have a very big pandas dataframe. I need to have many parallel subprocesses work with a portion of this one big dataframe. Let's say I have 100 partitions of this table that needs to be worked on in parallel. I want to avoid having to need to make 100 copies of this big dataframe as that will overwhelm memory. So the current approach I am taking is to partition it, save each partition to disk, and have each process read them in to process the portion each of them are responsible for. But this read/write is very expensive for me, and I would like to avoid it.

But if I make one global variable of this dataframe, then due to COW behavior, each process will be able to read from this dataframe without making an actual physical copy of it (as long as it does not modify it). Now the question I have is, if I make this one global dataframe and name it:

```
global my_global_df
my_global_df = one_big_df
```

and then in one of the subprocess I do:

```
a_portion_of_global_df_readonly = my_global_df.iloc[0:10]
a_portion_of_global_df_copied = a_portion_of_global_df_readonly.reset_index(drop=True)
# reset index will make a copy of the a_portion_of_global_df_readonly

do something with a_portion_of_global_df_copied
```

If I do the above, will I have created a copy of the entire `my_global_df` or just a copy of the `a_portion_of_global_df_readonly`, and thereby, in extension, avoided making copies of 100 `one_big_df`?

One additional, more general question is, why do people have to deal with Pickle serialization and/or read/write to disk to transfer the data across multiple processes when (assuming people are using UNIX) setting the data as global variable will effectively make it available at all child processes so easily? Is there danger in using COW as a means to make any data available to subprocesses in general?

[Reproducible code from the thread below]

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import contextlib
import pandas as pd

def my_function(elem):

    return id(elem)

num_proc = 4
num_iter = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([1]))
print(id(df))

with contextlib.closing(Pool(processes=num_proc)) as p:
    procs = [p.apply_async(my_function, args=(df, )) for elem in range(num_iter)]
    results = [proc.get() for proc in procs]
    p.close()
    p.join()

print(results)
```

Comment: Because of COW you can modify the dataframe in each subprocess without affecting the parent or sibling copies.

Comment: I understand that modifying the `my_global_df` from a subprocess won't modify the `my_global_df` in the parent process. But what I want to know is if copying a portion of `my_global_df` will effectively copy the entire `my_global_df` or just that portion that I am copying/modifying (e.g. .iloc[0:10])? If it will copy the entire thing, I will run out of memory as each subprocess will copy the entire `my_global_df`.

Comment: It only copies what you ask for. You get a new dataframe with just the rows/columns you ask for. You can verify by calling `.info()` on the original DF and the new one you create.

Comment: You don't really even need to use a global variable. Just pass the dataframe as a parameter to the child process worker function.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that Python will use Pickle to serialize the dataframe, which can be very expensive for big dataframes

Comment: Can you give insight on the general question as well? (Why UNIX users deal with serialization at all when they can just make the data global and it will make it instantly available to all processes?) –

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about the pickling part. Its been awhile since I've done this. I'll do a little fiddling. As for the why - its needed on Windows but "fork and process" is very much in unix's wheelhouse and should be done normally.

Comment: It also has me wondering whether pandas would work with COW shared memory on Windows. Don't know the answer to that one.

Comment: Per my understanding virtual copy and COW is UNIX specific behavior so I conjecture it would not work on Windows machines. But thank you for sharing your thoughts. I will also try to empirically verify this.

Comment: On windows, [CreateFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) allows copy on write. There's gotta be some way to do it!

Comment: I created some data `foo` in parent and printed `id(foo)` in parent and child. They were the same. In cpython, id() is usually the memory address of the variable. They would be different if pickle were involved.

Comment: The caveat in the python multiprocessing docs is in effect: _Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic._ basically, since the child has all of the parent code and data, including state held in the clibraries and all code up to the point of the new process, life can get dodgy.

Comment: Absolutely. To use this one would want to make sure only a single thread is running at the time of forking. But your comment about id is quite unexpected. I will try this.

Comment: Ha, the quick exercise is even more puzzling! So I passed a dataframe whose id is `4812380424`. I passed this df as argument to `Pool.apply_async` and in each process I ran a function that returns the id of the argument it received. Here is what I got: `[4775500040, 4775500040, 4775500040, 4775500040, 4812382048, 4812381768, 4812382160, 4812381768, 4812382048, 4790808136]` Why and how the repeat of the output ids?? I will post a reproducible code in the question itself for verification purposes. Please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Ah, I just realized the number of unique ids is equal to the number of processes I used. This makes sense.

Comment: And if you slightly modify the code to make the function parameter-less, and fetch the id of the df (which is global) directly, you will see that ids are all same. Which again brings me back to the question: Why bother with serialization at all when COW allows you to bypass it and makes the data available instantly?

Comment: I think the short answer is: You shouldn't. If we could trace poorly written or misapplied coding examples from internet searches through the world's code bases, it would dwarf the human genome project.

Comment: I take it you are saying one shouldn't bother with serialization and that the coders of the (UNIX) world who bothers with serialization are misapplying it? Or are you saying I should not risk using COW behavior to bypass serialization? (if so, could you please elaborate on some risks you foresee?)

Comment: The intermediate queue used for the async pool may pickle things. That's another research topic. I bumped into something kindof like this years ago and my memory is fuzzy, but I ended up with a global variable that held a list and I passed an index to the list down to the workers.

Comment: I'm saying absolutely use COW and that the serialization stuff on unix is misapplied.

Comment: Virtually all major open source packages uses Pickling, and does not try to rely on COW. One immediate reason I can think of is that these authors want to make the packages usable by Windows users too. But as long as one stays within UNIX world, I guess we have the luxury. This is excellent!

Comment: I can't see any immediate dangers of relying on COW. Unless/until there are others with differing opinions, I will just use global variables as well. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. This was enlightening and interesting.

Comment: Maybe a campaign to add `if platform.system() == "Windows":` to their code bases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, on a forking system such as Mac or Linux, a child process has a copy-on-write (COW) view of the parent address space, including any `DataFrame`s that it may hold. It is safe to use and modify the dataframe in child processes without changing the data in the parent or other sibling child processses.

That means that it is unnecessary to serialize the dataframe to pass it to the child. All you need is the reference to the dataframe. For a `Process`, you can just pass the reference directly

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_fctn, args=(my_dataframe,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

If you use a `Queue` or another tool such as a `Pool` then the data will likely be serialized. You can use a global variable known to the worker but not actually passed to the worker to get around that problem.

What remains is the return data. It is in the child only and still needs to be serialized to be returned to the parent.

Comment: This is not correct. Python multiprocessing still uses serialization/pickle to pass the data to the subprocess. So in this case, the dataframe would still BE PICKLED. For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600240/why-is-pickle-needed-for-multiprocessing-module-in-python