# How to share large read only dictionary/list across processes in multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a 18Gb pickle file which i need to be accessing across processes. I tried using

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
import cPickle as pkl
manager = Manager()
data = manager.dict(pkl.load(open("xyz.pkl","rb")))
```

However, I am getting the following issue:

```
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Someone suggested it might be because of socket timeout but it doesn't seem like it as increasing the timeout did not help.
How do I go about this. Is there any other efficient way of sharing data across processes?

Comment: `cPickle` ? you're using python 2 then? maybe you could give it a try with python 3.

Comment: I am able to load the pickle file without manager.dict. So, I doubt if that's the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is mostly a duplicate of [Shared memory in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124588/1256452), but you're specifically looking at a `dict` or `list` object, rather than a simple array or value.

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to share a dictionary or list like this, as the internals of a dictionary are complicated (and differ across different Python versions).  If you can restructure your problem so that you can use an `Array` object, you can make a [shared `Array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), fill it in once, and use it with no lock.  This will be *much* more efficient in general.

It's also possible, depending on access patterns, that simply loading the object first, then creating your process pools, will work well on Unix-like systems with copy-on-write `fork`.  But there are no guarantees here.

Note that the error you are getting, error number 11 = `EAGAIN` = "Resource temporarily unavailable", happens when trying to send an enormous set of values through a `Manager` instance.  Managers don't *share* the underlying data at all: instead, they *proxy accesses* so that each independent process has its own copy, and when one process update a value, it sends the update to everyone participating in the illusion-of-sharing.  In this way, everyone can (eventually, depending on access timing) agree as to what the values are, so that they all *seem* to be using the same values.  In reality, though, each one has a private copy.