# Python parallelizing functions using multiprocessing

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am new to python and using python 2.7.  I am writing a program to parse  raw re files . I have written a function which calls a file and puts every 4 line in a list . My file is big say 4 GB of raw dna data.

```
def filerd(f):
           identifier = []
           with open(f,'r') as inputfile:
            count = 1
            for line in inputfile:
              if count%4 == 1:
                identifier.append(line)
                count = count + 1
              else:
                count = count + 1
              return identifier
```

Now how can i parallelize this function so that i can get speedup.
Is there any way when i can run this function on 5 cores of my server?

Comment: What would be your idea of what parallelization might look like?

Comment: I am specifically looking for "for loop paralleism" :Comparing with C , the for loop can  be parallelized   openmp for loop directive .

Comment: Well, you will need to split your data into several chunks. Then you can use `multiprocessing` to process each of these chunks in a parallel process.

Comment: However, I believe that your code can be made much more efficient and faster, e.g. using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: So that means the process of splitting data into chunks can not be parallelized in python ? i have large file just need to iterate through it and create a list based on certain conditions? This iteration can not be parallelized?

Comment: The problem you are likely to run into is that you will need to pass the line data across to the child processes, which could be inefficient. It *might* be more efficient to have all subprocesses read the entire file, but only process every 4th line. E.g. subprocess 1 reads all lines but only processes line 1, 5, 9, etc. subprocess 2 does 2, 6, 10 etc

Comment: See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing about multiprocessing.Array which is a way of sharing memory between processes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can likely gain a lot of speed just from optimizing your function. I suggest to try the following:

```
import itertools

def filerd(f):
    with open(f, "r") as inputfile:
        return list(itertools.islice(inputfile, None, None, 4))
```

If you do not need the return value to be a list, but are fine with an iterator, you can remove the `list()`. Then, quite likely the slowest part will be loading the data from disk, which you need to do anyway.