# How to share data across two different process in Python

Tags: python

I have two different processes.

1. Generator.py: create some data and dump to disk
2. Control.py: Control script from where I can call Generator.py using subprocess.

What I am trying to achieve is that Control.py can receive the output of Generator.py without dumping it output to disk. I want to establish communication in such a way that Control.py can get data in memory from Generator.py.

Scenario is this:

```
Generator.py
def foo():
    myList = [1,2,3]
    return myList 

foo()

Control.py:
handleA = subprocess.Popen(["python",  "Generator.py"])
```

My Objective is to avial myList in Control.py. In this case how can I do this ?
I was planning to use multiprocessing.Queue but question is how to share Queue object with Generator.py through subprocess ?

What is best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared memory in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: I have two separate programs and no common function, how to share data produced from Generator.py to Control.py

Comment: why you launch it with subprocess can you use python process https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process because both of it is a python script. Because if you use process (not subprocess) you can use the queue interface to share the state with the two process

Comment: Do you mean I should add call in Generator.py as `Process(target=foo, args=(q,))` but how Control.py will get the data I will put in Generator.py ?