# How do I send and recieve variables through subprocess to different Python files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am totally new to subprocess and need to be able to send a variable from one python file to another using this library.

I have a little idea of how to send the data from the master file (something like this?):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'slave.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='string')
```

But how do I call that variable in the other file?

Unfortunately, I cannot use any other module because of the nature of my project.

Comment: Read it from standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is a little vague, but to answer your question as I understand it:

if your `slave.py` is executed every time you need to pass it a variable, you can pass it as an argument on the cli.

```
var1='simple data structure such as string, int etc.'
subprocess.call(['python', 'slave.py', var1])`
```

In `slave.py` you can then get this variable from `sys.argv`:

```
import sys
name_of_program = sys.argv[0]
var1 = sys.argv[1]
```

If your `slave.py` is running continuously there are several ways to communicate between processes on a same computer system:

- [Remote Procedure Calls - RPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html)
- Shared Memory - See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing) SO thread
- Using `stdin` as suggested in the comments (only for simple data structures like strings, int etc)

Comment: Ok, so I replaced `.call` with `.Popen` and now it passes the variable, while running both programs synchronously - just what I needed to do!