# Pytorch: RAM explodes when using multiprocessing SharedMemory and CUDA

Tags: multiprocessing, pytorch, gpu, shared-memory

I would like to use multiprocessing to launch multiple training instances on CUDA device. Since the data is common between the processes, I want to avoid data copy for every process. I'm using python 3.8's `SharedMemory` from multiprocessing module to achieve this following this SO [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257364/4029467).

I can allocate a memory block using SharedMemory and create as many processes as I'd like with constant memory (RAM) usage. However, when I try to send tensors to CUDA, the memory scales linearly with the number of processes. It appears as if when `c.to(device)` is called, the base data is copied for every process.

Does any one know why this is happening? Any ideas to mitigate this issue?

Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, get_context
import time
import torch
import copy

dim = 10000
batch_size = 10
sleep_time = 2
npe = 1  # number of parallel executions

# cuda
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    dev = 'cuda:0'
else:
    dev = "cpu"
device = torch.device(dev)


def step(i, shr_name):
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shr_name)
    np_arr = np.ndarray((dim, dim), dtype=np.float32, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    b = np_arr[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size, :]
    b = torch.Tensor(b)

    # This is just to explicitly copy the tensor so that it has nothing to do
    # with the shared memory block
    c = copy.deepcopy(b)
    
    # If tensor c is sent to the cuda device, then RAM scales linearly
    # with the number of parallel executions.
    # If c is not sent to cuda device, memory consumption is constant.
    c = c.to(device)
    
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    existing_shm.close()


def create_shared_block():
    a = np.random.random((dim, dim)).astype(np.float32)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes, name='sha')
    np_arr = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=np.float32, buffer=shm.buf)
    np_arr[:] = a[:]
    return shm, np_arr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create shared memory block
    shm, np_arr = create_shared_block()
    # create list of inputs to be executed in parallel
    inp = [[x, 'sha'] for x in range(npe)]
    print(inp)

    # sleep added before and after launching multiprocessing to monitor the memory consumption
    print('before pool')  # to check memory with top or htop
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    
    context = get_context('spawn')
    with context.Pool(npe) as pool:
        print('after pool')  # to check memory with top or htop
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        
        pool.starmap(step, inp)

    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

Comment: This might be due to the fact that CUDA needs page-locked pages to copy to the GPU memory. So what might be happening is that when you try to copy to the GPU, there is a duplication of memory to a page-locked memory region before copying it. Just one guess, but I'm not sure if that is the case.