# Shared Memory error while pickling object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm messing around with `multiprocessing.shared_memory` and am simply trying to pass a `datetime.now()` value around processes.  Piecing things together it seems that I can just pickle an object to turn it into bytes and place it on the shared memory buffer....  oh, if it was that simple.

Examples I've run across all focus on using this with [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing) , but there has to be more use for  it, right?

Here's what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from cachetools import cached, TTLCache
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, shared_memory
import pickle


def pickle_object(obj):
    return pickle.dumps(obj)

def unpickle_object(bytes):
    return pickle.loads(bytes)

def create_shared_block():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="shared_mem_test", create=True, size=1024)
    while True:
        p = pickle_object(datetime.now())
        print(p)
        shm.buf[0] = p
        time.sleep(5)


def process1(shr_name):
    while True:
        existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shr_name)
        print("p1 time is: ", unpickle_object(existing_shm.buf[0]))
        time.sleep(3)

def process2(shr_name):
    while True:
        existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shr_name)
        print("p2 time is: ", unpickle_object(existing_shm.buf[0]))
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Create shared block")
    shr = create_shared_block()

    # holder of processes
    processes = []

    p1 = Process(target=process1, args=(shr.name,))
    p2 = Process(target=process2, args=(shr.name,))
  
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    shr.close()
    shr.unlink()
```

This outputs:

```
Create shared block
pickled:  b'\x80\x04\x95*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x93\x94C\n\x07\xe7\t\x13\x140%\x04\x13\x14\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "objects.py", line 42, in <module>
    shr = create_shared_block()
  File "objects.py", line 22, in create_shared_block
    shm.buf[0] = p
TypeError: memoryview: invalid type for format 'B'
```

I'm trying to figure out why it's complaining about the unsigned bytes type (B). From what I can tell (not a numpy guy here) the sample numpy code linked above isn't doing a thing with unsigned bytes, so how did that example work, but this one didn't?  The pickled object is clearly in bytes:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x8c\x08datetime\x94\x93\x94C\n\x07\xe7\t\x13\x140%\x04\x13\x14\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'
```

Comment: What is the example that worked? As far as I can tell you are only showing an example that doesn't work.

Comment: My naive interpretation is that `shm.buf[0]` is a location for one byte (hence 'B') in the shared memory and you are trying to assign an array of bytes to it.

Comment: What happens if you try: `shm.buf[:len(p)] = p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by this statement: `shm.buf[0] = p`. Buffers don't have the same semantics as in C. You need to use list slice semantics in Python to assign the bytes into the buffer. Here is an example of how to make it work.

```bash
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> import pickle
>>> now_bytes = pickle.dumps(now)
>>> shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=1024)
>>> shm.buf[:len(now_bytes)] = now_bytes
>>> now2 = pickle.loads(shm.buf[:len(now_bytes)])
>>> now2
datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 19, 19, 57, 32, 566329)
>>> now2 == now
True
```

Comment: Once we use the syntax, shm.buf[:len(now_bytes)] = now_bytes then how can we know  that which shared memory position/array holds the particular value. ie: shm.buf[10] = 123