# Python Shared Memory Leakage

Tags: python-3.x, linux, python-multiprocessing, ipc, shared-memory

I ran the **first** example for the `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` class in the [Python documentation website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) on `Python 3.8`. It worked as **expected**. But when I attached to the shared memory from a **separate** script (the *creator script* will **wait** `30` seconds for **attachment**) as follows:

**Creator Script:**

```
def main():
    shm_a = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 10)
    buffer = shm_a.buf
    buffer[:4] = bytearray([22, 33, 44, 55])
    buffer[4] = 100

    print(shm_a.name)

    sleep(30) # added to the example code
    shm_a.close()
    shm_a.unlink()
```

**Attacher Script:**

```
def main():
    shm_b = shared_memory.SharedMemory('psm_2551129c') # psm_2551129c returned by the generator script
    array.array('b', shm_b.buf[:5])
    shm_b.buf[:5] = b'howdy'
    print(bytes(shm_b.buf[:5]))

    shm_b.close()
```

The following **errors** occurred in the *attacher* and *creator scripts*, **respectively**:

**Attacher Script Error:**

```
ahmad@Ahmad-Laptop:~$ /usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:203: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

**Creator Script Error:**

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:203: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/psm_7978b751': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_7978b751'
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: %r: %s' % (name, e))
```

Note that **after** the *attacher script* returns with error (and **before** the *creator script* returns), the **output** of `sudo lsof|grep -i psm` is as follows:

```
python3.8 13463                   root  DEL       REG               0,24                       3 /dev/shm/psm_2551129c
python3.8 13463                   root    3u      REG               0,24           10          3 /dev/shm/psm_2551129c (deleted)
python3.8 13463                   root    4u      REG               0,24           10          3 /dev/shm/psm_2551129c (deleted)
```

At the **same** time, `/dev/shm/psm_2551129c` does **not** exist (seems to be **deleted** **after** the *attacher script* returns).

How can I **resolve** these errors?

Comment: Is the library implementation **bogus**? The following link seems to be **related**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65731003/6661026