# How to share a global super big dictionary to concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, caching, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a huge list of 900K dictionary objects (position) that will reference a big dictionary to compute values.

The big dictionary has at least 50 keys and the values are sets and dicts in which each set, or dict have at least 85K items. This dictionary will act as a lookup or cache for each position

How can I share the big_dictionary to all the processes? I don't want to copy big_cache to each process.

Thanks,

```
big_cahce = {
'A_LOOKUP':{85,000 elements},
'B_LOOKUP':{10,00 elements},
'C_MAP': {'K1': 1, 'K2':2,...., 'K2500':25000}
}

positions = [
{'pos_id':1, pos_type:'a', ...},
{'pos_id':2, pos_type:'a', ...},
.
.
.
{'pos_id':900000, pos_type:'a', ...},
]

def process_position(position):
    if position['post_type'] in big_cache['A_LOOKUP']:
        position['VALUE'] = big_cache[C_MAP].get(position['KEY'])

    if position['CCY'] in big_cache['B_LOOKUP']:
       position['VALUE'] = big_cache[C_MAP].get(position['KEY'])

    return position

def execute(positions_list):
    res = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = executor.map(process_positions, positions_list)
        for fut in futures:
            res.append(fut)
    return res
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared memory in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: Which operating system? If you are on a forking system like linux, then the global variable state at the moment the processes are created is readable by the processes.

Comment: @tdelaney but due to CPython's reference counting mechanism, the copy will happen pretty quickly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - True. A copy-on-write is triggered for an entire page when a variable is read. But its a pretty fast write (comparatively!) and only affects the subset of data you actually touch. In this case, since workers don't do much, it would not be a good idea. But just pickling the new `position` and sending it back is huge compared to work done.

Comment: Since your workers don't do much compared to the overhead, you are much better off doing this sequentially.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I looked into that but is not using concurrent.futures

Comment: @tdelaney running on linux. so you're saying that I dont have to pass the big_cache? in my real code everything is OOP. Also, I have something similar without passing anything to the workers and it works better that sequentially

Comment: Each process in the pool has a copy-on-write view of the parent's memory. So, it will see the global data - but any changes are private to the subprocess only. If big_cache and positions are already cooked when you run the pool, then they are visible and you should not pass them to the pool. instead of passing `positions`, pass the index to `positions` that each should use. As mentioned, when you read a variable, python writes its reference count, and that will trigger the 4k page to be copied at the hardware memory management layer. So, you'll get some copying each each process.

Comment: @tdelaney I'll try that right away. Thanks

Comment: following @tdelaney's advice If memory still presents a problem, you might set a `max_tasks_per_child` value, so as the cache slowly gets copied into the child, you eventually recycle the process to start fresh (memory wise). Unfortunately I can't find any way to utilize python 3.12's new immortal objects from within runtime without writing an extension module.