# Python slows down the more threads I use with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu, numba

**This is not a question related to the overhead time loss resulting from creating different proceses.**

I am programing an economic model which requires to perform many calculations for different individuals. The structure of the code is a nested loop. To achieve some speed gains I am parallelizing the outer loop, since each iteration is independent from the other. To track the performance of my code, I am measuring how much it takes to perform one iteration within the second loop.

The problem I am having is that when I parallelize the outer loop, operations within the second loop take more time. My first impression was that maybe numpy or numba where parallelizing my code behind the scenes, without I actually noticing that. To adress such a thing I discovered that I could set the amount of cores the BLAS library is using. In my case I am using the MKL BLAS libray. After I set the threads to be used to 1, the comparison between single thread operations and multiple thread opeations should be an apple-to-apple comparison given that both are using one and only one thread. However, the more cores I add to the multiprocessing pool, the longer it takes to compute within threads operations. I attach Figure that shows the time it took to compute each operation in the second loop for the same outer loop depending on whether it was the only thread, or other threads where working on some other processes. Clearly, the more threads, the longer it takes to compute the same operation.

[FIGURE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BTGP.png)

I believe the problem is not caused by the multiprocessing library, since I have tried to "parallelize the hard way" which basically mean open different python terminals and run the same program on each of them. The performance loss is equivalent to the one I am facing with multiprocessing.

**My question is, why does this occur? In my code I am specifically setting only one core to do one task, so when I parallelize I don't see how the fact that other cores are working on different things, affect the performance of the core that was already working on one thing.** Is there something that I can do to adress such a problem? I have done quite of research on the issue but nobody seems to mention that, most of the problems are just related to overhead time for creating different process. The multiprocessing documentation does not mention that either. Do you think the issue will persist in languages that allow for multithreading instead of multiprocessing? I am considering the posibility of moving into languages like Julia which allow multithreating where this reduction in performance might not occur, but I am not sure if this is actually true.

Find here I an example code that reproduces the dynamics of my problem.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import time
import mkl
import multiprocessing

mkl.set_num_threads(1)


np.random.seed(0)

@njit()
def task1(x):

    return x**(1-0.4)/(1-0.4)

def second_loop(i,x):

    y = np.random.rand(1,1000)
    time_passed = []
    for j in range(15):
    
        tic = time.time()
        x = task1(x)
        x = x+i
        np.matmul(y,x)
        toc = time.time()
        time_passed.append(toc-tic)
        print(toc-tic)
    if i == 0:
    
        return time_passed




import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from statistics import mean 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    average_time = []

    for cpu_numbers in range(1,9):
        x = np.random.rand(1000,5000)
        args = [(i,x) for i in range(cpu_numbers)]
        pool_obj = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_numbers)
        time_passed = pool_obj.starmap(second_loop, args)
        pool_obj.close()

        average_time.append(mean(time_passed[0][2:]))

    plt.plot(np.arange(1,9),average_time,marker="X",ls="--",mfc = "r",mec="r",ms=8)
    plt.xlabel("Threads")
    plt.ylabel("Seconds")
    plt.savefig("Figure.png")
```

Comment: Modern CPUs can boost to higher clock speeds when only one core is in use. Maybe that's affecting your results?

Comment: Hi Raphael, that sounds about right. I just tested the cpu speed and the more threads I add to the pool, the slower the cpu speed is. I am not  an expert in comptuers, do you think there is a solution for that? Many thanks!

Comment: I am not sure as that is not my expertise, but I would assume that you can't do anything about this. At least not from a software point of view. You could OC your CPU multicore-boost clock, or downclock the single-core boost and then recheck your results. If this is affecting a real-world program, you could try other libraries, such as numba for parallelizing.

Comment: You could also double-check by using a third-party CPU benchmark tool (e.g. Prime95) while your program is running, to see if it's just a Python thing or actually a global effect.

Comment: First of all, multiprocessing needs to send data to each process. The more there are processes and the slower it gets until the pickling becomes the main bottleneck and the scalability becomes bounded. This is a fundamental problem of CPython (especially since threads are useless in such a case and there are not much alternatives). This is a problem when large inputs are transferred. The thing is `x` is large here. You should make it shared to make this faster assuming this is the bottleneck.

Comment: What is mkl and what is mkl.set_num_threads(1) meant to achieve?

Comment: Moreover, indeed, frequency scaling can impact scalability. This is frequent on modern CPUs. The reason is power consumption which is limited. Power scale in `W=F*V²` and `V` tends to grow (sub-)linearly with `F` so increasing the frequency consume a lot of power (and energy too since the wall clock time is not reduce so much). The reason the frequency is increased is that most applications are actually sequential (poorly optimised though parallelism is hard and not always possible to apply).

Comment: Finally, shared resources typically cause the scalability not to be perfect. For example, the L3 cache is shared, so if it is saturated, then each of the N threads can operate slower than 1 because of *shared resource contention*. The same thing applies for the RAM.

Comment: @CtrlZ The MKL is an Intel library providing linear-algebra/math functions like matrix multiplication. It is optimized and parallel so `np.matmul` is. `mkl.set_num_threads(1)` is meant to avoid thread over-subscription.

Comment: Hi Jérôme, thanks for your comments. I will investigate more on the topic, since I am not an expert of the field. What do you mean by making `x` shared? Do you think I can improve performance somehow? Maybe using a language that performs multithreating instead of multiprocessing?

Comment: Regarding shared memory, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing) may be useful. I did looked carefully the answer but some use locks that may serialize a part of the execution which is also not great for performance. It should at least remove the pickling/unpickling Python significant overhead. It looks like the locks are not always mandatory (e.g. if there is no writes like in your case I think). I cannot tell whether this is a bottleneck in your case (dependent on the target machine) but this is a common significant overhead.

Comment: Honestly, I find all of this cumbersome to perform for such a simple operation. Python is a mess in parallel computing and this is mainly due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). If this is fine for you to use another language, then you can pick any native language like C, C++, Rust. All of them can create threads that are not limited by things like a GIL. In C/C++, you can easily parallelize a code using OpenMP (it should be done in 1 line here : `#pragma omp parallel for`). No need for explicit shared memory, nor JITs.

Comment: An alternative is to use the multithreading feature of Numba. Indeed : Numba njitted functions are not limited by the GIL (since the Python code is compiled to a native one and there are no CPython object in njitted functions by design). You can enable Numba parallelism with the `parallel=True` flag. For loops are explicitly parallelised using `nb.prange(...)` instead of `range(...)`. Note that the parallelism model of Numba is limited but it should be enough here. This is certainly the best solution for this specific code.

Comment: Note also that njitted Python code can only run Numpy or basic Python code, not function coming from modules (like `statistics` I guess)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, if you post it I will accept your answer. Unfortunately my code is quite compliated and I can't paralleize using numba, since I need to save and load some arrays and this is not allowed in numba. I will carefully study the post you mentioned to see if I get any speed gain. However, I also think @Raphael was right and the cpu boost is afecting my results. In any case, thanks a lot for your time and help.