# Run while loop every second

Tags: python, csv

I have written a script to read from a instrument and writing the data to a CSV-file. The time interval between each sampling can be set by the user. One second sampling rate is quite common. I have used time.sleep and tried to extract the processing time for the script by using timeElapsed = timeEnd - timeBegin. The problem is that this isn't good enough. The time is drifting so every now and then the script jumps over a second. On my computer it happens approx every 2-3 minutes. So my question is how I can increase the accuracy of the timing.

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import os.path

no_of_meas = 200
cur_meas = 1
time_interval= 1    #time between each sample given in seconds, 1 second is the lowest recommended value

with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    while cur_meas <= no_of_meas:
        timeBegin = time.time()
        cur_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S.%f')  
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
        data = [[cur_time, cur_meas]]
        a.writerows(data)
        fp.flush()   #flush and os.fsync to be sure that data is written to disk
        os.fsync(fp.fileno())
        print(', '.join(map(str, data)))
        cur_meas += 1
        timeEnd = time.time()
        timeElapsed = timeEnd - timeBegin
        time.sleep(time_inter-timeElapsed)
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping, check whether the current time is greater-or-equal to some time; this way, the error can not accumulate.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13151104/3881403

Answer (score 0):

You should not reset your base time on every call, since you are creating a new time scale which is slightly off. You have to do the calculation in place from a global time base. And you need to use floats in order to make sure Python does not do any integer rounding.

Just the relevant parts:

```
interval = 1.0
start_time = time.time()

with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    while cur_meas <= no_of_meas:
        next_in = (start_time + (cur_meas - 1.0) * interval) - time.time()
        if next_in > 0.0:
            time.sleep(next_in)
        # your measuring code.
```

This way the code will calculate when the current measurement would be expected and sleeps until then or continues immediately when the time is already reached.

Comment: Thank you this works really good. I have ran the script over night on two computers, approx 62000 samples, I haven't missed a second and it hasn't jumped over any seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base the delay on the actual time rather than a per iteration delay. The following is a possible alternative way of dealing with it which will not drift over a long time, but will use fractionally more CPU.

```
import time

def tick(time_interval):
    next_tick = time.time() + time_interval
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)     # Minimum delay to allow for catch up
        while time.time() < next_tick:
            time.sleep(0.2)

        yield True
        next_tick += time_interval

time_interval = 1.0
ticker = tick(time_interval)

while cur_meas <= no_of_meas:
    # Do measurement code
    next(ticker)
```

Individual iterations will be to the next 0.2s (or however fine you need). If an iteration is delayed (e.g. CPU loading), this will allow a 'catch up' every 0.2s until time is synchronised again.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I could be that i mistyped something but the time jumped quite a lot. Sometimees I got 2-3 samples each seconds, other times it jumped ovre a second or two.

Comment: Can you copy/paste again, I had made a change a little while after posting it. 2-3 samples will only occur if the script froze for over a second, it will then tick every 0.2s until it catches up.

Comment: It works better now. It samples every second and the accuracy seems pretty good.