# How to run the function endlessly at intervals in Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop, telegram-bot

I want to take the function every hour run , but if i insert my code into the bot file, he stop working:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()      
today = now.day
hour = round(now.hour, 2)

while True:
    if today == now.day and (hour > 22.00 and hour < 23.00):
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, random.choice(welcomes))
        today += 1
    else:
        time.sleep(3600)
```

How i can fix it and to realize this function?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `if` condition. What difference does `today` make if this doesn't form part of the bot's response, and it's just going to sleep again for 3600 seconds?

Comment: Or, looking again, you don't actually want your function to run every hour, you want it to run _once per day_ at a set time interval, and you're checking for that interval every hour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule a repeating event in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398661/schedule-a-repeating-event-in-python-3)

Comment: @roganjosh, I want the function to send a message once a day to a user at a certain point in time and at the same time not interfere with the work of other functions

Comment: 1. `now.hour` returns an `int` - no rounding is necessary. 2. Don't auto increment `today` - what will happen on the month's last day? 3. Use threading, or you'll be blocking the other functions you have.

Comment: @TDG , thanks , i didnt think about it

Answer (score 0):

The third line,

```
hour = round(now.hour, 2)
```

`round` will return `22.00` from 22:00 ~ 22:59, and `23.00` from 23:00 ~ 23:59.

So, your condition below never got it.

```
(hour > 22.00 and hour < 23.00)
```

(`22.00` is not larger than `22.00` and `23.00` is not smaller than `23.00`.)

Corrected condition is

```
(hour >= 22.00 and hour < 23.00)
```

or

```
(hour > 22.00 and hour <= 23.00)
```

or maybe you want

```
(hour == 22.00)
```