# How can I repeat something for x minutes in Python?

Tags: python, time, repeat

I have a program (temptrack) where I need to download weather data every x minutes for x amount of hours. I have figured out how to download every x minutes using `time.sleep(x*60)`, but I have no clue how to repeat this process for a certain amount of hours.

UPDATE:
Thank you to everyone who posted a solution.
I marked the example using "datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=x)" as the best answer because I could understand it the best and it seems like it will work very well for my purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the time you want to stop doing whatever it is you're doing, and check each time that the time limit hasn't expired. Like this:

```
finish_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
while datetime.datetime.now() < finish_time:
    do_something()
    sleep_for_a_bit()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, even though I didn't know it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a scheduler.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit of overkill, but for running background tasks, especially if you need a GUI, I'd recommend checking out the PyQt route with [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsystemtrayicon.html) and [QTimer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtimer.html)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but just put it in a loop that runs a sufficient number of times. For example, to download every 5 minutes for 2 hours you need to download 24 times, so:

```
for i in range(24):
    download()
    sleep(5*60)
```

If you need it to be parameterizable, it's just:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import ceil
betweenDLs = 5 # minutes
totalTime = 2*60 # minutes
for i in range(int(ceil(totalTime/betweenDLs))):
    download()
    sleep(betweenDLs*60)
```

Comment: This is a simple solution, but it might not be quite what is wanted if the time to execute the function is similar in magnitude to the time between executions.

Comment: Thank you. Your first example works well. I'll just use "for i in range(totalTime/frequency)" and that should work well. I know it will round (as I'm using integers, not floating point) but it does not have to be very accurate.

Comment: Try to avoid using range() unless you are needing for a real list. If you just need to run a for use xrange instead. This will optimize your code, because range() allocs a whole list, while xrange() is just an iterator. NOTE: in python3 there's only range() and behaves like xrange()

Comment: I would use select() for doing this :p

Comment: UPDATE: nevermind, using "for i in range(totalTime/frequency)" does not appear to work that well (meaning it is too inaccurate to use). Thanks, I'll check out xrange() and select().