# Task Scheduling Across a Network?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, distributed-computing

Can you recommend on a `python` tool / module that allows scheduling tasks on remote machine in a network?

Note that the solution must be able to not only run certain jobs/commands on remote machines, but also verify that jobs etc are still running (for example, consider the case where a machine dies after a task has been assigned to it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RPyC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpyc/) or Remote Python Call, is a transparent and symmetrical python library for remote procedure calls, clustering and distributed-computing.  Here an example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPyC):

```
import rpyc
conn = rpyc.classic.connect("hostname")  # assuming a classic server is running on 'hostname'

print conn.modules.sys.path
conn.modules.sys.path.append("lucy")
print conn.modules.sys.path[-1]

# a version of 'ls' that runs remotely
def remote_ls(path):
    ros = conn.modules.os
    for filename in ros.listdir(path):
        stats = ros.stat(ros.path.join(path, filename))
        print "%d\t%d\t%s" % (stats.st_size, stats.st_uid, filename)

remote_ls("/usr/bin")

# and exceptions...
try:
     f = conn.builtin.open("/non/existent/file/name")
except IOError:
     pass
```

---

To check if the remote server has died after assigning it a job, you can use the ping method of the Connection class.  The complete API is described [here](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/api%3acore).

Comment: @Ralph: thank you. What happens if machine dies after a task has been assigned to it? will `RPyC` help in such a case?

Comment: you will need to code that part, have the task send a signal after it's done and check that

Comment: @OneOfOne: so 'rPyC' is just a connector to the remote machine that invokes the job on it? what's the difference between this and programatically conneting (thourhg `SSH`) to the remote machine and invoking the job on it?

Comment: more elegant solution and programmable, you can easily code up what you need using the multiproccessing (or threading) module and rPyC, check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rpyc/

Comment: @Ralph: thank you. is there any process / service that needs to be run on the remote machines in order for `RPyC` to be able to connect to them? or can it just connect to any remote machine given its IP?

Answer (score 2):

Fabric (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html) is a pretty good toolkit for various sys admin and deployment tasks. It comes with a few pre defined tasks but also gives you the flexibility to add what you need.

I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use [Python WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html), for *NIX based systems it's a [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python) around SSH and CRON.