# Are there any in-memory job schedulers in Python similar to Ruby's Rufus-Scheduler

Tags: python, asynchronous, scheduler

Just wondering if Python has something like: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

I don't want any database (postgres, redis, etc...) to be attached to it.

I checked out RQ and Celery, but couldn't find if they were capable of doing this without a database.

Ideally I wouldn't have to spin up any workers. I want this running in the main python process. I believe Ruby does this through EventMachine.

Comment: So what specifically are you looking to do? Schedule task for a certain time? Run tasks periodically? Anything else?

Comment: Run tasks periodically. I'd like a little job that runs on a set interval that connects to different APIs like twitter, facebook, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one time scheduled tasks, check out the [APScheduler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler/1.01), here is the introduction page http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/#introduction

For periodic tasks, check out this SO question - [Executing periodic actions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/how-to-execute-periodic-actions-in-python)

Comment: Ahh I was just about to post this :P