# Do something when minute = 10, 20 , 30, 40, 50, 00

Tags: python, time

I am new to python and im trying to make a script. I want the script to keep looking at the time and for every 10 minutes i want to execute another command. So far i've got:

```
import time

min = time.strftime("%M")
```

How should i approach the rest?

it should run as some kind of service... it should be someting like:

```
if min == 00, 10, 20, 30, 40 or 50
    do this
```

Comment: do you want to run a task every 10 minutes, or does it have to run at exactly 10, 20, 30, etc. minutes past the hour?

Comment: why not run it as a cron job? cron'll take care of the scheduling and then your script can simply focus on the actual job. Cron can schedule in 10 minute intervals quite easily.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8600161/1510289

Comment: I want it to run exactly at 00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, and i want to try to avid con jobs...

Comment: Should it run once? Run as many times as possible in those minutes? Look into: `while` loops and what `min % 10` equals.

Comment: it should run as some kind of service... it should be someting like:

if min == 00, 10, 20, 30, 40 or 50 do this or that

Comment: What operating system? How one implements "some kind of service" varies greatly between operating systems.

Comment: Tell us more about why you want to avoid cron. It is one (the easier one) of two ways that "some kind of service" is implemented in debian.

Comment: rob, i know how to make it a service.. I just do not know how to make the script...

Comment: rob, well basically because it theoretically should not be every time minutes, but every time the clock says 00, 10, 20 etc, and also because i have a feeling that it shouldn't be very hard in python...

Comment: Time for a punt at the new close reasons, I think. This qualifies as _'Unclear what you're asking'_. Please clarify your requirement, and edit your question to include more information.

Comment: Are you familiar with the syntax of the crontab file? `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/dhojgaard/myscript.py` does precisely what you are asking for.

Comment: ``*/10 * * * * /home/dhojgaard/myscript.py`` is more terse, same thing though.

Comment: Yeah, i know that rob, but im just a guy trying to learn python while solving this task.. I am a nerd and just because there is an easy way it does not always mean you should go that way.. I wouldn't learn anything new by that...

Comment: Part of learning a new tool is learning when not to use it. As a high level interpreted language Python is just not a good choice for scheduling. Keeping a python instance up and running just to check the time makes very little sense when they're already a cron process doing exactly this within your OS.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want using Python. Although from reading the comments I doubt it's the most efficient means of doing so:

```
import time


while True:
    curr_min = time.strftime('%M')
    curr_sec = time.strftime('%S')
    if int(curr_min) % 10 == 0 and int(curr_sec) % 10 == 0:
        print('Make script go now')
        time.sleep(59)
```

It checks once a minute if the minutes are a multiple of 10 and executes if it is.

UPDATE: This should do what you asked but it's really starting to be more apparent that another method would be a more logical/efficient fix

Comment: But how do you start it at exactly 00 seconds?

Comment: A stopwatch? The OP asked for something that ran if the minutes are 00, 10, etc and this will do that. If he wants it at exactly 00:00 he should have included that in his question.

Comment: Fair enough. But eventually you're gonna miss a ten minute slot because the lines before ``sleep()`` use up wallclock time and your ``sleep(60)`` will sleep through the whole 10 minute spot.

Comment: If i want it to be exactly when the time turns to 00, 10, 20 etc how should i approach it?

Comment: To address @dhojgaard's issue, you switch to `int(curr_min) % 10 == 9` and then sleep at 1 second intervals until `int(curr_min) % 10 == 0`.  On the other hand, @dhojgaard, if you need as "exact" as possible, then you should look into a real-time extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```
import time

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    if now.tm_min % 10 == 0:
        # Do what you need to do
        time.sleep(559 - now.tm_sec) #sleeps until roughly the next 10 minute mark
```

That said, you should really use a cron job...

Comment: If you start this before a 10 minute mark it should execute at :00 every time provided that whatever code you need to run doesn't take up much time (i.e. no more than a millisecond or two). 

If, for some reason, the loop starts a few seconds late it should automatically correct for that and hit the :00 mark next time around. It also won't spinning its wheels the whole time, it only get's hyper alert right around the 10 minute mark.

Again though, use cron. You can even code the actions in python and just use cron to run "$python my_script.py" every 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

```
current_minute = datetime.now().minute

if current_minute in [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]:
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a correct _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)