# perform an action at a certain time with the web.py framework

Tags: python, web.py

I am currently starting to work on a web server running web.py . If I understand it correctly, the whole thing is implemented as some kind of a loop that listens to the requests at the specified port and reacts accordingly.

I would like the server to perform a certain action at a certain time without a request that triggers it. What is the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it within python you can look at using the threading class.

More information on how to do it here: [Executing periodic actions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to set up a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_job) in the system, which will execute your script (which can be written in Python or other language).