# Obtain reference to thread I forgot to keep a reference for

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, if I do something like the answer in this thread: [Executing periodic actions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python)

eg:

```
>>>import time, threading
>>> def foo():
...   print(time.ctime())
...   threading.Timer(10, foo).start()
...
>>> foo()
```

I understand that each `10` seconds I'm starting a new `Timer` thread that will wait the time, then create a new timer, etc, and it will run indefinitely.

Obviously, there is nothing in the output of `dir()` as I didn't assign it a name.

Is there any way to get a reference to this `Timer`, for instance to `.cancel()` it?  Or is the only way to stop it to have kept a reference to it from the beginning?

I know this is very poor practice, but it demonstrates my more general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timer`s are a `Thread` subclass, and like all `Thread`s, they show up in enumeration. You wouldn't necessarily know which one is *the* timer, but you can get a list of all running threads with `threading.enumerate()`.

If you just want to cancel *all* outstanding `Timer`s, you could do:

```
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    if isinstance(thread, threading._Timer):  # In Py2.7 at least, Timer is a function wrapping the class _Timer
        thread.cancel()
```

Obviously, this would be playing unsportingly if your code is just one library among many, since it would cancel `Timer`s spawned elsewhere; not cricket that.