# Python: Call function at fixed rate

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

The function *do_something* should be called at fixed rate (e.g. 10 seconds).

I found links such as [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) or [Executing periodic actions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python). Unfortently those implementing gave the same resoluts like i would have had

```
time.sleep(10)
```

at the end of the *while*-loop, which is not the behavior i am seeking for.

Hier is an example output:

```
2015-01-01 13:00:00
2015-01-01 13:00:10
2015-01-01 13:00:21
2015-01-01 13:00:31
2015-01-01 13:00:42
```

where the wish behavior should have been:

```
2015-01-01 13:00:00
2015-01-01 13:00:10
2015-01-01 13:00:20
2015-01-01 13:00:30
2015-01-01 13:00:40
```

At present this is my solution:

```
import time
import datetime

def do_something():
    print(datetime.now())

period = 10

while True:
    do_something()
    t = time.time()
    time_to_sleep = period - ( t % period )
    time.sleep( time_to_sleep )
```

Unfortently with this method and my raspberry pi 3 I am unable to achive a stable timestamps at a fixed rate. Here is an output example:

```
2015-01-01 13:00:00
2015-01-01 13:00:10
2015-01-01 13:00:23
2015-01-01 13:00:33
2015-01-01 13:00:40
```

Any ideas?

PS
This is a small program.

Comment: What is "takt"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman he means "interval".

Comment: Did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/474570/6324080?

Comment: @DanielRoseman fixed, thanks. Takt was changed with rate, but interval is correct as well.

Comment: Why are you doing `period - ( t % period )`?

Comment: The issue here is that the sleep function does not take into account the time it takes for your function to execute.

Comment: I linked to a Q&A I replied to a few months ago (using only standard python, no extra packages). The problem here is that indeed you're not clocking how much time the processing takes.

Comment: @K.Kirsz, i saw the first answer at the link you sent. I tried with sched and it did not work. I will try it with twisted package

Comment: What is resolution of your `time.time` - seconds only or milliseconds?

Comment: @Błotosmętek return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: "Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. " - but anyway the only thing I can think of is that your `do_something` function does a lot more than just printing a timestamp, and therefore the timestamp is delayed - try putting it at the very beginning of your function.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `period - ( t % period )` is the rest time to the next timestamp.