# A function that repeats every N milliseconds for N amount of time

Tags: python, multithreading, xlsxwriter, adc

I am a beginner at Python Programming. What I am essentially trying to create is a program that will sample the voltage from an ADC every millisecond, put this data into a matrix, and then export it to an Excel file. Right now I'm using placeholders for the ADC data. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import xlsxwriter
import time
import numpy
import threading

a = numpy.array(['Time (ms)','Current (A)'])    #Writes header values, sets up array a
maxtime = 200   #Limit for how long the program will run, in ms
elapsed = 0

def readdata(maxtime):
    global elapsed
    global a
    if elapsed <= maxtime:
        threading.Timer(0.01, readdata)
        elapsed +=1
        b = numpy.array(['Test1', 'Test2']) #'Test1' and 'Test2' Will eventually be replaced with ADC data
        a = numpy.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)   #Combines the arrays
    else:
        generatespreadsheet(a)


def generatespreadsheet():
    global a
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".xlsx") #Define workbook name as date and time
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()    #Adds the first sheet
    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(a):
        worksheet.write_row(col, row, data) #write the array in Excel
    workbook.close()

readdata(maxtime)
```

The issue I'm having is that the code appears to do nothing at all. Not even throwing error codes. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I have switeched over to using a generator, code follows:

```
    import xlsxwriter
import time
import numpy
import threading

a = numpy.array(['Time (ms)','Current (A)'])    #Writes header values, sets up array a
maxtime = 200   #Limit for how long the program will run, in ms
elapsed = 0

def do_every(period,f):
    def g_tick():

        t = time.time()
        count = 0
        while True:
            count += 1
            yield max(t + count*period - time.time(),0)
    g = g_tick()
    while True:
        time.sleep(next(g))
        f()
        global elapsed
        global maxtime
        elapsed += 1
        if elapsed >= maxtime
            generatespreadsheet()



def readdata():
    global a
    b = numpy.array(['Test1', 'Test2']) #'Test1' and 'Test2' Will eventually be replaced with ADC data
    a = numpy.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)   #Combines the arrays




def generatespreadsheet():
    global a
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".xlsx") #Define workbook name as date and time
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()    #Adds the first sheet
    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(a):
        worksheet.write_row(col, row, data) #write the array in Excel
    workbook.close()
    exit()


do_every(0.001,readdata)
```

Comment: I have not worked much with pythonic threads but feels like you are missing the start operation here. `Some_thread.start()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing periodic actions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python)

Comment: you need to start your thread. do  https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#timer-objects . But are you sure you want to start so many threads? at a glance it looks like you will end up with about 200 threads. Not sure if you machine can handle that... My advise would be to change the logic...

Comment: Thanks for your help @bayko, though I'm not sure where or how to implement this in the code.