# Cancellable and non-blocking delay

Tags: python, multithreading

I've seen this post [Python periodic timer interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722864/python-periodic-timer-interrupt)
and understand that

```
threading.Timer( t, function).start()
```

is the most common solution for a non blocking delay or timer in Python.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Can you have several of these running at the same time?
2. How would you cancel-reset a specific running Timer?

Comment: Concerning (1): what happened when you tried to use more than one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancellable threading.Timer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812344/cancellable-threading-timer-in-python)