# Pausing periodic tasks in Python

Tags: python, task, scheduling, periodic-task

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python), I would like to execute foo() every 10 seconds, but I would also like to be able to pause the periodic execution.

How do I do this?

Comment: We've been using the excellent [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more top level handling of jobs. It allows you to pause jobs, set interval schedules, etc.

Comment: It was something like this I was looking for, it works great, thanks!