# How to Improve Timing Precision in Python Script for DMX Control

Tags: python, tags, precision, timing

I have a Python script that controls DMX lighting via the OLA library. The script reads color values from a CSV file and sends them to a DMX controller at regular intervals of 120ms.

I'm using time.perf_counter() for timing, but I'm experiencing drift over time. Specifically, when the script sends a large sequence of over 1000 values, it starts to drift more than 40ms after passing 100 values. I need extremely high precision for my application.

```
import array
import csv
import time
import warnings
from ola.ClientWrapper import ClientWrapper
from tqdm import tqdm

# Suppress DeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

def custom_sleep(duration, get_now=time.perf_counter):
    now = get_now()
    end = now + duration
    while now < end:
        now = get_now()

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header row
        return [list(map(int, row)) for row in reader]

def DmxSent(state):
    pass

def main():
    universe = 1
    dmx_values = read_csv('dmx_values.csv')

    wrapper = ClientWrapper()
    client = wrapper.Client()

    with open('log_file.txt', 'w') as log_file:
        for values in tqdm(dmx_values, desc="Processing DMX Values"):
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            data = array.array('B', values + [0] * (512 - len(values)))
            client.SendDmx(universe, data, DmxSent)
            custom_sleep(0.120)  # Hold for 120ms
            elapsed_time = (time.perf_counter() - start_time) * 1000
            log_file.write(f"Elapsed Time: {elapsed_time:.2f} ms\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I implemented a custom_sleep function that uses time.perf_counter() to achieve more precise timing, but the drift still occurs.

I've added logging to measure the actual time taken for each operation, but the drift persists. i confirmed this by recording the light source at 25fps with a video camera and observed the drift at around value 100.

I expect the timing to have high precision with minimal drift over time.

I'm running the script on a MacBook Air M1. The DMX interface I'm using is an Enttec USB Pro.

I'm considering integrating C/C++ for the timing-critical parts but would like community advice on the best approach.

Comment: try recording the start time of your program and sleep until start time + 120ms * operation number rather than for a fixed 120ms

Comment: Your C/C++ idea sounds like a good one.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyglet.clock](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clock.html#module-pyglet.clock) should not drift over time but you will still have the delay of your function being run after the tick. This should be relatively constant each time your function is called so may not be an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have to take care of the time required for the commands sent through the driver to control the device. Therefore, you cannot start timing it "after" you send the command.

More specific, you have to call your custom_sleep with start time

`custom_sleep(0.120, lambda: start_time)`

It will avoid the drift but you have to be careful about the gap is sufficient for the command.

You could also improve the precision and consistency by including the timing of all operations inside your timer like

```
   time_interval = 0.120
   gap = 0
   start_time = time.perf_counter()
   for values in tqdm(dmx_values, desc="Processing DMX Values"):
        data = array.array('B', values + [0] * (512 - len(values)))
        client.SendDmx(universe, data, DmxSent)
        elapsed_time = (time.perf_counter() - start_time) * 1000
        log_file.write(f"Elapsed Time: {elapsed_time:.2f} ms\n")
        gap = gap + time_interval
        custom_sleep(gap, start_time)  # Hold for 120ms
```

I don't think your sleep function contribute to the drift but you are using a busy loop to check the timing. I am not going into details because there are too many methods. You could refer to [Executing periodic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions)

For real time applications, you could consider using [rtos](https://www.freertos.org/zh-cn-cmn-s/about-RTOS.html). It could be as simple as setting up a timer and calling the api of the ola library you are using but it really depends on your situation.