# Python: Event Schedular like quartz

Tags: python

I am looking for an  event scheduler like quartz in java  for my python project .

Please suggest me some good scheduler in Python

My Requirements

1) Send an email or sms to the user after some interval

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/) is you want.

This is the example:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(hours=3)
def some_job():
    print "Decorated job"

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`celery`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) might be an overkill as well as `quartz` for the task:

```
@celery.task
def sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg):
    "send mail here"

sendmail.apply_async(args, countdown=n) # send email in `n` seconds
```

Comment: @Sebastian sending mail is not only my task it could be anything like sending sms

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution would be:

```
from aqcron import At
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

# Event scheduling
event_1 = At( second=5 )
event_2 = At( second=[0,20,40] )

while True:
    now = datetime.now()

    # Event check
    if now in event_1: print "event_1"
    if now in event_2: print "event_2"

    sleep(1)
```

And the class aqcron.At is:

```
# aqcron.py

class At(object):
    def __init__(self, year=None,    month=None,
                 day=None,     weekday=None,
                 hour=None,    minute=None,
                 second=None):
        loc = locals()
        loc.pop("self")
        self.at = dict((k, v) for k, v in loc.iteritems() if v != None)

    def __contains__(self, now):
        for k in self.at.keys():
            try:
                if not getattr(now, k) in self.at[k]: return False
            except TypeError:
                if self.at[k] != getattr(now, k): return False
        return True
```