# How to schedule an action in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, schedule

I'd like to know how to preform an action every hour in python. My Raspberry Pi should send me information about the temp and so on every hour. Is this possible?

I am new to python and linux, so a detailed explanation would be nice.

Comment: Write a python script and add it to your [crontab](http://blog.davidsingleton.org/raspberry-pi-webcam-a-gentle-intro-to-crontab/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a python code for having those readings from sensors in to text or csv files and send them to you or to dropbox account

and then put a cron job in linux to run that python script every hour

type in your command line

```
sudo su
```

then type

```
crontab -e
```

In opened file enter:

```
/ 0 * * * * /home/pi/yourscript.py
```

where /home/pi/yourscript.py is your fullpath to python script and it will execute this "yourscript.py" every 60 min.

To send your code to you - you have to choose some way-
1) you can send it to your inbox
2) to dropbox account
3) to sql data base
In any case you have to write script for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can check out the [**sched**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module (in the Python standard library).

personally, I'd keep it simpler, and just run your script every hour using a system scheduler like [**cron**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

a basic crontab entry to run hourly (on the hour) might look like this:

```
0 * * * * /home/foo/myscript.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you *really* want to write a scheduler in Python, see some of the answers given here:  [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, but can you please provide me an easy example, I am very new to python.

Comment: many ways to approach it described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: but again.  I would just write a simple script, and add it to crontab for scheduling.  read up on `cron` daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set up a cron job to call a python script every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Use systemd. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-systemd

You can schedule it when you want, and monitor it with journalctl