# How can I use the time library in python to do something every ten minutes?

Tags: python

I want to be able to use the time module to do some snippets of code, but I'm a bit confused. Granted this is the first time I use it so I don't know exactly how to. Here's my goal however:

```
import time
(every 10 minutes)
    # do something
```

Comment: are you on *nix? If you are cron can be used to easily do this

Comment: Would this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: dm03514 I don't know what *nix is. Justin Ethier, that post both scares and confuses me.

Comment: By *nix he means some variant of Linux or Unix. It's using the asterisk as a wildcard marker.

Comment: Oh my fault. Yes I'm using linux (ubuntu). I also have mac os at home and would want to implement it there too. I'm reading through the wiki on cron right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time

tenminutes = 600

while true:
  time.sleep(tenminutes)
  print "This is a reminder"
```

This would print something to the console every 10 minutes

Comment: I see. So if I wanted to, say, print something to the terminal every ten minutes, could I do

while true:

time.sleep(tenminutes)
print "This is a reminder!"

Comment: @NormanB yep, I just updated how it would look if you wanted to do that

Comment: Okay that works, thanks very much that should help get me started