# Crontab vs Schedule jobs in python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, cron

I tried to run my python scripts using crontab. As the amount of my python scripts accumulates, it is hard to manage in crontab.

Then I tries two python schedule task libraries named [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/) and [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule).

The two libraries are quite the same in use, for example:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The library uses the `time` module to wait until the exact moment to execute the task.

But the script has to run all the time and consumes tens of Megabytes memory. So I want to ask it is a better way to handle schedule jobs using the library? Thanks.

Comment: Why are the scripts hard to manage with cron? There are [those who prefer a Python solution because they don't want to depend on cron being installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python), but if that is not a problem, why would cron be worse than python?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Thanks for your reply. Because crontab cannot recognize the directory of '.','..','~' and etc... So I just want to run my scripts controlled by the management tools such as supervisor.

Comment: `cron` runs in your home directory, it recognizes `~` and `.` and `..` just fine but you have to know what to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2013 - when this question was created - there were not as many workflow/scheduler management tools freely available on the market as they are today.

So, writing this answer in 2021, I would suggest using Crontab as long as you have only few scripts on very few machines.

With a growing collection of scripts, the need for better monitoring/logging or pipelining you should consider using a dedicated tool for that ( like [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), [N8N](https://n8n.io), [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) ... )

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and setup a crontab to run those. We use that in production and it works really well.

Another is to use something like celery to [schedule tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html).

Comment: Unless I missed something, the original poster didn't say he was using Django.