# python-How to make sure the script crawls periodically?

Tags: python, json

I have written a python script that crawls a website and creates a json response file with the crawled data. Now, I want to use the json response but how do I make sure that the script executes periodically so that the json file is not static but keeps changing as the website which is being crawled changes it data?

Comment: I'd look at using `cron` if you have it or if you're on Windows without cygwin you could look at `at` or apparently that's been deprecated in favor of `schtasks`

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for CRON.

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like
>   computer operating systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score -1):

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)