# How to run django application in background

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application that sends emails to customers. I want this application to run in the background after a certain time, is like a job/quote process.  What could be best way to do this with Python/Django?

Comment: This depends on the system, you're on. On Linux, you would use cron. On Windows, you would use Task Scheduler. With Python alone, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/373335/1741542

Answer (score 2):

> How to run django application in background?

This question makes no sense. Django is a web based framework. What do you mean by running a web application in background?

I think you want to ask: *How to run periodic background tasks in `Django` application?*

For that purpose you may use [`Celery`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). Celery with the help of Message Queueing service allows you to perform tasks in background. It also supports execution of custom script at mentioned duration. Check: [Periodic tasks in Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use docker
And then you can run your web application in the background.....
[DockerFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B4Il.png)

If you want to run script background you can you CRONTAB or scheduler.