# Make python script execute some functions every hour

Tags: python, scheduler

So lets say i have this code:

...

```
connect()
find_links()
find_numbers()
```

in fact what it does is login to an account,get some numbers and one link:
example:

> 1.23, 1.32 , 32.1, 2131.3 link.com/stats/
>
> 1.32, 1.41 , 3232.1, 21211.3 link.com/stats/

so all i want to do is make these functions run every one hour
and then print the time so i can then compare results.I tried:

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=3600 )

def do_that():
     connect()
     find_links()
     find_numbers()
     print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

but this just executes one time the functions and then just prints the date.

Comment: Did you try to lower the interval to something less that 3600 seconds in order to prove that it "executes only once"?

Comment: have u tried using python's sched.scheduler or threading.Timer ?

Comment: here is a better answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Answer (score 2):

This should call the function once, then wait 3600 second(an hour), call function, wait, ect. Does not require anything outside of the standard library.

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime


def func():
    connect()
    find_links()
    find_numbers()
    print(datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Thread(target = func).start()
    while True:
        sleep(3600)
        Thread(target = func).start()
```

Comment: Why are you using threading here? Could you add some clarification please for us?

Answer (score 0):

Your code may take some time to run. If you want to execute your function precisely an hour from the previous start time, try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


def do_that():
    connect()
    find_links()
    find_numbers()
    print(datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    starttime = time.time()
    while True:
        do_that()
        time.sleep(3600.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 3600.0))
```